# How to determine distribution from command line?

Tags: linux, distributions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bash: Get Distribution Name and Version Number](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6345/bash-get-distribution-name-and-version-number)

Given (root) access to a machine with Linux through the command line(over ssh), how can I determine which distribution is actually running on the system?