# How to install red5 & Java on centos 6.4

Tags: centos, java

There are many tutorials out there but not so many for 6.4 and it seems people are having problems with running either Java 6 or 7 and Ant.

So does anyone know where to find a definitive guide?

Should Java be version 6 or 7 and can I just `yum install java`? Then which version of `red5` should I be installing? On their site they have video tutorials that don't even reflect the sitemap of their site!

so confused..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always go with the Oracle/Sun java and try to not use the OpenJDK version. I usually run into incompatibilities, and I end up having to install it anyway.

You can't just `yum install java` you have to go to Oracle's website and download Java/JDK directly from there. I'd recommend getting the latest version if you can.

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

The naming of Java has always been a bit of a mess, I'd suggest downloading the version from the URL above, it's the Java SE version. Make sure you select the `.rpm` version and also make sure you select the appropriate version for your system's architecture (32-bit or 64-bit).

[image: ss of download]

It's pretty straightforward. Once you download it you'll need to execute the download, which should begin the installation using the contained `.rpm` files.

I like using this method since it allows me to manage the Oracle JDK just like any other RPM on my system, so it's easier to uninstall it and also you can then have multiple versions installed along side one another.

#### Running red5

As @terdon has mentioned in his answer, `red5` is pretty straightforward to download and execute. I just confirmed that it works fine with the OpenJDK version of Java on my Fedora 19 system, I would expect it to work just fine on CentOS 6.x without issue as well. I also tried it with Oracle's JDK so either installation of Java should suffice here.

I'll just add the following extra bits to the directions in @terdon's answer. I'd suggest changing directories to the directory that `red5` was untarred into like so:

```
$ cd /path/to/red5
$ ./red5.sh
```

After it starts up you can see what ports it's listening on using this command:

```
$ netstat -tapn | grep java
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp6       0      0 :::1935                 :::*                    LISTEN      9419/java           
tcp6       0      0 :::47663                :::*                    LISTEN      9419/java           
tcp6       0      0 :::9999                 :::*                    LISTEN      9419/java           
tcp6       0      0 :::5080                 :::*                    LISTEN      9419/java
```

After starting the server you can confirm that it's starting by navigating to the URL `http://localhost:5080`. You'll see a video load on a page like this:

[image: ss of red5 test page]

Comment: so mine says i685 which is 32 bit i think. would you place the redhat in /var/www/html ????

Comment: @CharlieBunt - yeah that sounds like its 32-bit. The red5 you mean? Probably not, this is it' own server. That directory is usually meant for httpd (Apache) the web server. You can find out a system's bitness using the methods I outlined in this Q&A: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77718/32-bit-64-bit-cpu-op-mode-on-linux/77724#77724

Comment: sorry i mean the rpm - which directory to usually put that in to extract?

Comment: @CharlieBunt - it doesn't matter. You can download them anywhere and then install them using `rpm -ivh some.rpm` or `yum localinstall some.rpm`. You'll need to do this using `sudo` or be root when you do these commands.

Answer (score 2):

I installed it with no issue at all using both `openjdk` and Sun's JDK so you *might* be fine with `yum install java`. Still, I'm on a Debian and @slm is the resident Red Hat guy so I'd follow his advice.

Whichever Java Development Kit you choose to install, running `red5` is very easy. You just need to choose the latest release from [their website](http://www.red5.org/red5-server/) (1.0 at the time of writing), download the newest package and extract the files.

Just create a directory where you want to install this (for example `$HOME/Setups`), `cd` into that directory and run these commands:

```
wget http://red5.org/downloads/red5/1_0/red5-1.0.0.tar.gz
tar xvzf red5-1.0.0.tar.gz 
cd red5-1.0.0-build-jenkins-red5-226/
./red5.sh
```

If all goes well, you should see a lot of text and finally:

> [INFO] [Launcher:/installer] org.red5.server.service.Installer - Installer service created

You now have a running `red5` server. You can check by going to `http://localhost:5080`.

You can now either add the `red5.sh` script to your path or make a link to it in a directory already in your path. For example:

```
sudo ln -s ~/Setups/red5-1.0.0-build-jenkins-red5-226/red5.sh /usr/local/bin/red5
```

You (and all other users on the system) can now simply run `red5` to start the server.

Comment: These are both really great answers but I chose the one more specific for choosing the confusing array of versions. Thank you very much.

Comment: I am following your instructions now so thanks - I don't know why two answers can't be right. AND it is working thanks to you both!

Comment: @CharlieBunt no worries, slm's is the more complete answer, accept it!