# Obtaining information about system hardware

Tags: linux, hardware

If I want to accurately save information about the hardware I am using as a reference, what is the best way to do it? Are the contents of `/proc/meminfo` sufficient?

Comment: "hardware you are using" as in "what physical hardware is there" (also see: `lspci`, `lsusb`) or "how much of my machine is currently occupied (for some value of occupied)" (also see: `top`, `df`)?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz:I am interested in keeping info about how "strong" my machine is as a reference. I think meminfo has the info e.g. how much memory, processors etc but I am not sure what info generally is good to keep besides that.

Comment: Added this question as faq to hardware tag.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are several tools that you can use to capture specifics about your hardware. I would make use of the following set of tool  to accomplish this.

**NOTE:** I would say no, `/proc/meminfo` is not sufficient, unless you just want to know how much RAM your system has.

### System Info

#### [lshw](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lshw)

This is a good tool for getting a general purpose list of what's currently included in your system from a hardware perspective.  It also includes what drivers are being used so it's usually the first tool I go to for such things. It can show you specific hardware (network, CPU, RAM, etc.) and also output the results in a short format (shown below) as well as output in JSON, HTML, or XML.

*Example*

```
$ sudo lshw -short | head | expand
H/W path         Device     Class          Description
======================================================
                            system         900X3C/900X3D/900X4C/900X4D (System SKUNumber)
/0                          bus            NP900X4C-A07US
/0/0                        memory         128KiB BIOS
/0/4                        processor      Core i7 (To Be Filled By O.E.M.)
/0/4/6                      memory         32KiB L1 cache
/0/4/7                      memory         256KiB L2 cache
/0/4/8                      memory         4MiB L3 cache
/0/5                        memory         32KiB L1 cache
```

#### [dmidecode](http://www.nongnu.org/dmidecode/)

This tool takes a different approach and shows a dump of the system's DMI tables. This is essentially the view of the system's BIOS, in human readable form.

*excerpt*

> **dmidecode**  is  a tool for dumping a computer's DMI (some say SMBIOS)
>   table contents in a human-readable format. This table contains a
>   description of the system's hardware components, as well as other useful 
>   pieces of information such as serial numbers and BIOS revision. Thanks  to 
>   this table,  you  can retrieve  this information without having to probe for 
>   the actual hardware.  While this is a good point in terms of report speed
>   and safeness, this also makes the presented information possibly unreliable.
>
> The DMI table doesn't only describe what the system is currently made of, it 
>   also can report the possible evolutions (such as the fastest supported  CPU
>   or the maximal amount of memory supported).
>
> SMBIOS  stands  for  System  Management BIOS, while DMI stands for Desktop 
>   Management Interface. Both standards are tightly related and developed by the
>   DMTF (Desktop Management Task Force).

*Example*

```
$ sudo dmidecode | head -20
# dmidecode 2.12
# SMBIOS entry point at 0xdac46000
SMBIOS 2.7 present.
64 structures occupying 2909 bytes.
Table at 0xDAC45000.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 24 bytes
BIOS Information
    Vendor: Phoenix Technologies Ltd.
    Version: P02ABK
    Release Date: 09/19/2012
    Address: 0xE0000
    Runtime Size: 128 kB
    ROM Size: 3072 kB
    Characteristics:
        PCI is supported
        BIOS is upgradeable
        BIOS shadowing is allowed
        Boot from CD is supported
        Selectable boot is supported
```

#### [hwinfo](http://www.sarata.com/manpages/man8/hwinfo.8.html)

Another venerable tool for capturing a full snapshot of your system's overall hardware. Similar to `lshw`, but IMO, probably the best overall tool for collecting this type of info. This is the tool that I generally reach for.

```
$ hwinfo --cpu | head -14
01: None 00.0: 10103 CPU
  [Created at cpu.446]
  Unique ID: rdCR.j8NaKXDZtZ6
  Hardware Class: cpu
  Arch: X86-64
  Vendor: "GenuineIntel"
  Model: 6.58.9 "Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3517U CPU @ 1.90GHz"
  Features: fpu,vme,de,pse,tsc,msr,pae,mce,cx8,apic,sep,mtrr,pge,mca,cmov,pat,pse36,clflush,dts,acpi,mmx,fxsr,sse,sse2,ss,ht,tm,pbe,syscall,nx,rdtscp,lm,constant_tsc,arch_perfmon,pebs,bts,rep_good,nopl,xtopology,nonstop_tsc,aperfmperf,eagerfpu,pni,pclmulqdq,dtes64,monitor,ds_cpl,vmx,est,tm2,ssse3,cx16,xtpr,pdcm,pcid,sse4_1,sse4_2,x2apic,popcnt,tsc_deadline_timer,xsave,avx,f16c,rdrand,lahf_lm,ida,arat,epb,xsaveopt,pln,pts,dtherm,tpr_shadow,vnmi,flexpriority,ept,vpid,fsgsbase,smep,erms
  Clock: 905 MHz
  BogoMips: 4789.57
  Cache: 4096 kb
  Units/Processor: 16
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
```

This is nice info since it includes just about anything you'd want to know about the make, model, and feature set of your given CPU.

### CPU Info

#### [lscpu](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lscpu)

This tool will just show you specifics about your CPU.

*Example*

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 58
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3517U CPU @ 1.90GHz
Stepping:              9
CPU MHz:               1701.562
CPU max MHz:           3000.0000
CPU min MHz:           800.0000
BogoMIPS:              4789.57
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              4096K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

#### [cpuid](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cpuid)

If you want to get into the nitty gritty details of your system's CPU there's `cpuid`.

```
$ cpuid -1 | less
   version information (1/eax):
      processor type  = primary processor (0)
      family          = Intel Pentium Pro/II/III/Celeron/Core/Core 2/Atom, AMD Athlon/Duron, Cyrix M2, VIA C3 (6)
      model           = 0xa (10)
      stepping id     = 0x9 (9)
      extended family = 0x0 (0)
      extended model  = 0x3 (3)
      (simple synth)  = Intel Core i3-3000 (Ivy Bridge L1) / i5-3000 (Ivy Bridge E1/N0/L1) / i7-3000 (Ivy Bridge E1) / Mobile Core i3-3000 (Ivy Bridge L1) / i5-3000 (Ivy Bridge L1) / Mobile Core i7-3000 (Ivy Bridge E1/L1) / Xeon E3-1200 v2 (Ivy Bridge E1/N0/L1) / Pentium G1600/G2000/G2100 (Ivy Bridge P0) / Pentium 900/1000/2000/2100 (P0), 22nm
   miscellaneous (1/ebx):
      process local APIC physical ID = 0x3 (3)
      cpu count                      = 0x10 (16)
      CLFLUSH line size              = 0x8 (8)
      brand index                    = 0x0 (0)
   brand id = 0x00 (0): unknown
   feature information (1/edx):
      x87 FPU on chip                        = true
      virtual-8086 mode enhancement          = true
      debugging extensions                   = true
      page size extensions                   = true
      time stamp counter                     = true
      RDMSR and WRMSR support                = true
      physical address extensions            = true
      machine check exception                = true
      CMPXCHG8B inst.                        = true
      APIC on chip                           = true
      SYSENTER and SYSEXIT                   = true
      memory type range registers            = true
      PTE global bit                         = true
      machine check architecture             = true
      conditional move/compare instruction   = true
      page attribute table                   = true
      page size extension                    = true
      processor serial number                = false
...
```

#### [/proc/cpuinfo](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc)

If you just want to query info that the Linux Kernel provides about your CPU without having to utilize a tool, such as `lscpu`, you can always grok the `/proc` filesystem. In the same manner that you originally asked with `/proc/meminfo`, other hardware is also represented here  as well, for example, the CPU.

```
$ head /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 58
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3517U CPU @ 1.90GHz
stepping    : 9
microcode   : 0x1b
cpu MHz     : 892.406
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
```

#### References

- [Determine the intel CPU family for C compiler?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115162/determine-the-intel-cpu-family-for-c-compiler/115172#115172)
- [32-bit, 64-bit CPU op-mode on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77718/32-bit-64-bit-cpu-op-mode-on-linux/77724#77724)
- [How to install hwinfo on Fedora 19/20 and CentOS 5/6](http://www.binarytides.com/install-hwinfo-fedora-centos/)
- [Linux tool to dump x86 CPUID information about the CPU(s)](http://www.etallen.com/cpuid.html)

Comment: Wonderful list. Should `/proc/cpuinfo` be in this list as well? I see it also contains some information pertaining to the processor.

Comment: @Ramesh - sure I'll add it. All it's info is included in `lscpu`. One of my posts that I reference below showed this.