# Type and the speed of CPU using the lscpu command

Tags: command-line, command, cpu

[image]

I want to determine the type and speed of my CPU so I executed the CPU command, However, I have some confusion, so from my output I can't really determine what is my CPU type and my speed is 1600 MHZ, is that right ?

I used

> cat /proc/cpuinfo

and I got that my model name is Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU , is that my cpu type ?

Comment: To better understand what you mean by `cpu type`, what are some examples of what would call  `cpu type`?

Comment: Please do not turn text in to pictures: it makes it difficult for our blind users, and users with slow internet. You can select and past text into your question, then re-select it and click `{}`

Comment: Related: [Obtaining information about system hardware](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154803/obtaining-information-about-system-hardware)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never knew about the lscpu command.

The man page says its based on the first CPU only.   The "rate" may "change".

seems the lscpu is under change -- newer ones have a -V (--version) option, on my ubuntu 15.04 system it says:

```
leisner@t7400:/tmp$ lscpu --version
lscpu from util-linux 2.25.2
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5430  @ 2.66GHz
Stepping:              6
CPU MHz:               2667.000
CPU max MHz:           2667.0000
CPU min MHz:           2000.0000
```

On another system is just says:

```
CPU MHz:               800.000
```

But in cpufreq-info it says:

```
current CPU frequency is 800 MHz.
cpufreq stats: 2.40 GHz:0.02%, 2.40 GHz:0.00%, 2.30 GHz:0.00%, 2.20 GHz:0.00%, 2.10 GHz:0.00%, 1.90 GHz:0.00%, 1.80 GHz:0.00%, 1.70 GHz:0.04%, 1.60 GHz:0.00%, 1.50 GHz:0.00%, 1.40 GHz:0.00%, 1.30 GHz:0.01%, 1.10 GHz:0.00%, 1000 MHz:0.00%, 900 MHz:0.01%, 800 MHz:99.91%  (5851)
```

(this is an 8 core i7).

Answer (score 2):

That is basicly what you get. You should now try looking google for Intel processor list by given information on speed (1600 Mhz) and the models name (What do you mean by asking your cpu type?). I am guessing between those:
P7500
T5200
T5470
U9600

Answer (score 1):

it is type for a computer, Intel is the make, model is 32bit or 64 bit, the word type indecates what it is used for, make is who makes it, and model is what kind it is. it is a dual core meaning two cpu's put together in one die. like what type of car is it?

words and there usages:

```
type : a category of people or things having common characteristics.
make : the manufacturer or trade name of a particular product.
model : is a particular brand of item sold under a marque by a manufacturer
```