# How to check Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, architecture

I want to install a package, and it has different versions for different OSes. The description in the package site is like this

```
X86-64 Linux 3.0 Kernel
```

I looked it up and found people saying to use

```
uname -r
uname -m
```

I tried it and got this:

```
3.2.0-24-generic
x86_64
```

Does this tell me the Linux I'm using is x86_64 and 3.2.0 Kernel? What does `-24-generic` mean?

Comment: @slm : How is this a duplicate? This question is about identifying **the kernel**, that question is about identifying **the CPU**.

Comment: @slm So it does not answer 2 of the 3 questions in the last para here ;)

Comment: @goldilocks - OK, OK, twist my arm...As soon as it closes we can reopen..8-)

Comment: Related: [32-bit, 64-bit CPU op-mode on Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77718/32-bit-64-bit-cpu-op-mode-on-linux)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`3.2.0` is the version of the [source code](https://www.kernel.org/) used to compile this kernel.  These can be four numbers long (e.g. 2.6.32.55) indicating a patch level on that version.  However, this [four digit system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel#Version_numbering) was only used for version 2.6 kernels starting at 2.6.8. I.e., it is not used with 3.x kernels, which are the 3 numbers, *release-major-minor*.  Note the subtle difference from the three number *major-minor-patch level* system commonly used with software.

`-24-generic` indicates a patch level and configuration used by the distro, *24* being their patch level, and *generic* being the configuration used in compiling.  This patch level does not necessarily reset/change for different kernel source versions; the distro either applies the patches unchanged (so, e.g., `3.2.1-24-generic`) or they increment the patch level (`3.2.1-25-generic`).

The most significant aspects are the source version number and the configuration style.  The later is important because it indicates significant differences in the way the kernel was actually configured for build.

This doesn't reveal which architecture the kernel was built for -- e.g., `x86_64` -- but the `uname -m` output does.

Answer (score 4):

That means that you have a 64bit linux kernel. And the version is 3.2.

Precisely it is the 24th release of this kernel. And it is the generic one. This means that the kernel can be used for desktop as well as server systems.