# machine hardware name, processor type and hardware platform

Tags: hardware

The followings are the machine hardware names, processor types and hardware platforms returned by `uname`:

on a server (with some 64-bit Linux distribution)

```
-bash-4.1$ uname -m
x86_64
-bash-4.1$ uname -p
x86_64
-bash-4.1$ uname -i
x86_64
```

on my laptop (Thinkpad T400 with 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04)

```
$ uname -m
i686
$ uname -p
i686
$ uname -i
i386
```

I wonder if machine hardware name and processor type are always the same thing?

What is hardware platform? Why does it seem to indicate  something about the OS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Hardware platform (`uname -i`) tells you what architecture the software was compiled for, typically 32-bit or 64-bit.

The `uname -m` tells you the architecture about the system itself, think motherboard here.

The `uname -p` tells you the architecture of the CPU.

#### What's the difference between system and CPU

I believe these 2 switches, `-m` and `-p` are what confuse people the most. It's possible to have a system that has one type of architecture (say 32-bit) but to utilize a CPU that offers a different architecture (64-bit).

This isn't that common and so in practice you'll typically see `-m` and `-p` showing up as offering the same architectures.

#### References

- [List of CPU architectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CPU_architectures)
- [32-bit, 64-bit CPU op-mode on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77718/32-bit-64-bit-cpu-op-mode-on-linux/77724#77724)

Comment: In "Hardware platform (uname -i) tells you what architecture the software was compiled for, typically 32-bit or 64-bit.", by software do you mean the OS or the uname utility or something else?