# is my linux ARM 32 or 64 bit?

Tags: arm, 64bit, 32bit

under an intel I know I can look at the outcome of `uname -m` to know if my OS is 32 or 64 bit, but under ARM this gives:

```
armv7l
```

I deduced from

```
file /usr/bin/ls
```

that I'm on a 32-bit OS, but how can I know this in an easier way?

Comment: arm 7 is 32 bit. `ARMv8-A architecture, announced in October 2011,[6] adds support for a 64-bit address space and 64-bit arithmetic.` — wikipedia

Comment: @richard I was guessing so, but then what is the name of the 64-bit variant?

Comment: I don't have access to an ARM machine but what is the output of `uname -a` and `gcc -v`? Those might be helpful.

Comment: `Announced October 2011, ARMv8-A (often called ARMv8 although not all variants are 64-bit such as ARMv8-R) represents a fundamental change to the ARM architecture. It adds a 64-bit architecture, named "AArch64", and a new "A64" instruction set. AArch64 provides user-space compatibility with ARMv7-A ISA, the 32-bit architecture, therein referred to as "AArch32" and the old 32-bit instruction set, now named "A32" ARM announced their Cortex-A53 and Cortex-A57 cores on 30 October 2012.` — http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#64.2F32-bit_architecture

Comment: Arm was the last of the 32bit cpu to go 64bit (excluding those that died). Most went 64bit and then died, because of poor marketing — assuming that being better is enough. The Intel x86 was the second to last, though it was AMD that added 64 bit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246007/how-to-determine-whether-a-given-linux-is-32-bit-or-64-bit

Comment: Kinda related Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246007/how-to-determine-whether-a-given-linux-is-32-bit-or-64-bit/6200504#6200504

Comment: Also, 'getconf LONG_BIT' will spit out the # bits of the _OS_ (not necessarily the processor)

Comment: `uname -m` will show `aarch64`, therefore anything different than that on a arm processor is 32.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

There are several gradations, since you can run a 32-bit or mixed operating system on a 64-bit-capable CPU. See [64-bit kernel, but all 32-bit ELF executable running processes, how is this?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134391/64-bit-kernel-but-all-32-bit-elf-executable-running-processes-how-is-this/134394#134394) for a detailed discussion (written for x86, but most of it applies to arm as well).

You can find the processor model in `/proc/cpuinfo`. For example:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
Processor       : ARMv7 Processor rev 10 (v7l)
```

ARMv7 (and below) is 32-bit. [ARMv8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARMv8#ARMv8-A) introduces the 64-bit instruction set.

If you want to see whether your system supports 64-bit binaries, check the kernel architecture:

```
$ uname -m
armv7l
```

On a 64-bit processor, you'd see a string starting with `armv8` (or above) if the `uname` process itself is a 32-bit process, or `aarch64` if it's a 64-bit process. (See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45125516/possible-values-for-uname-m)

Comment: I don't contest your answer, but unfortunately android IS A LINUX, so, there suppose to be some command, SOMEWHERE that show it locally and not to read a documentation on some page

Comment: @THESorcerer Android uses a Linux kernel but it is not a Linux system. It does not have Linux user land tools (only a very small subset). On Android, I think 64-bit support is consistent in the base OS, so `cat /proc/$$/maps` will let you know whether the system is 64-bit or 32-bit from an adb command line.

Comment: I believe Raspberry Pi 3, which is ARMv8 (CRC, no optional Crypto) will report `armv7l` even though its ARMv8. So I'm pretty sure the wrong CPU will be reported.

Comment: @jww If it reports `armv7l`, it means you're running a 32-bit kernel. You can run a 32-bit kernel on a 64-bit CPU. If you want information about the CPU, read `/proc/cpuinfo`.

Comment: uname -m just returns "aarch64".  /proc/cpuinfo doesn't always contain a name for a processor either.

Comment: @Halsafar If `uname -m` returns aarch64, it means you're running a 64-bit kernel.

Answer (score 33):

As richard points out, `armv7` variants are all 32-bit, so there is no redundant label `armv7-32`, etc.

On a linux system, you can easily, although not truly definitively, check by examining a common executable:

```
> which bash
/bin/bash
> file /bin/bash
/bin/bash: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV) ...
```

I say "not definitively" because it is possible to run 32-bit executables on a 64-bit system.

There does not appear to be anything foolproof in `/proc` or `/sys`; the output from `/proc/cpuinfo` *may* provide some significant clues.  If for some reason you need an automated check, creating a table mapped to the "model name" field seems like one potentially sound method (other fields, including "model", "cpu family", etc. look optional -- they don't appear at all for me on a Broadcom 2708 ARMv6 processor).

Comment: So armv7l is 32 bit right?

Comment: @bakalolo Read the question and the accepted answer slowly ;)

Comment: Great answer; using `bash` to see if the CPU architecture it's 32-bit or 64-bit :). A bit counter-intuitive, but I love it. Thanks !

Answer (score 18):

Seems like most ways to see bit count is to somehow know that arm7=32 bit and while that may be true but what about

```
pi@rpi9:~ $ getconf LONG_BIT
32
```

And if you want to look for the cpu model I normally use arch

```
root@rpi4:~# tr '\0' '\n' </proc/device-tree/model;arch
Raspberry Pi Model B Rev 2
armv6l

pi@rpi9:~ $ tr '\0' '\n' </proc/device-tree/model;arch
Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2
armv7l
```

Comment: getconf LONG_BIT is very straightforward

Comment: This should be the selected answer; `getconf` is a POSIX command and it works on Linux, macOS and BSD.

Comment: this command returns 32 bit on a system that reports aarch64 with uname -m that also has cpuinfo output consistent with current 64 arm kernel (where model name is not in the output)

Answer (score 15):

Install the 'lshw' package.

```
# lshw
...
    description: Computer
    product: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2
    width: 32 bits
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

```c
// -*- compile-command: "gcc -Wall -o sizeof sizeof.c && ./sizeof" -*-

#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define size(t) { t x; printf("%s:\t%3lu bit\n", #t, CHAR_BIT * sizeof x); }

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  size(char);
  size(short);
  size(int);
  size(long);
  size(void*);
  return 0;
}
```

The address size is `void*`.

Comment: [`sizeof` returns `size_t` which must be printed out using `%zu`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/940087/995714). Using the wrong format specifier invokes undefined behavior

Comment: and size of void* isn't necessarily the architecture bit width. Have you ever heard of [x32 ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI) https://sites.google.com/site/x32abi/

Comment: Similarly, 
getconf -a|grep LONG_BIT

Comment: This doesn't tell you about anything other than the nature of *your compiler*.

Answer (score -5):

Nope it's a 64-bit computer. It's an Allwinner H8, witch is a double ARM-7. 8 cores, 64 bits, powervr, sgx 544, at double speed (700mhz).

So no, it's capable of being 64 bit. Just the OS might be 32.

Comment: where did you find that the OP's using Allwinner H8? The architecture is armv7l which is clearly not a 64-bit one

Comment: It's better to demonstrate a way to find the desired information from *within* the system instead of using third-party information from external sources. This is better suited to be a comment than an answer (hence all the down-votes).