# How can I tell what version of Linux I'm using?

Tags: linux, ssh, version, info, system-information

Often times I will ssh into a new client's box to make changes to their website configuration without knowing much about the server configuration. I have seen a few ways to get information about the system you're using, but are there some standard commands to tell me what version of Unix/Linux I'm on and basic system information (like if it is a 64-bit system or not), and that sort of thing?

Basically, if you just logged into a box and didn't know anything about it, what things would you check out and what commands would you use to do it?

Comment: Related: [How to write a script that effectively determines distro name?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/23050)

Comment: Related: [How can I reliably get the operating system's name?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92199/how-can-i-reliably-get-the-operating-systems-name/92218#92218)

Comment: `cat /etc/*release*` works on most popular distros

Answer (score 115, accepted):

If I need to know what it is say Linux/Unix , 32/64 bit

```
uname -a
```

This would give me almost all information that I need,

If I further need to know what release it is say (Centos 5.4, or 5.5 or 5.6)
on a Linux box I would further check the file `/etc/issue` to see its release info ( or for Debian / Ubuntu `/etc/lsb-release` )

Alternative way is to use the `lsb_release` utility:

```
lsb_release -a
```

Or do a `rpm -qa | grep centos-release` or `redhat-release` for RHEL derived systems

Comment: In 2016 it does not seem like `lsb_release` works any longer with modern distros. I tested the command on Amazon Linux AMI release 2016.03 and CentOS Linux 7 and it was not found. It seems like ls `cat /etc/os-release` is the best solution currently with `uname -a` somewhat usable if a bit opaque (e.g. Amazon Linux AMI release 2016.03 vs. Linux ip-x-x-x-x 4.4.11-23.53.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jun 1 22:22:50 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux)

Comment: Well Done (y) :)

Comment: For me `uname -a` says 20.04.1 while `lsb_release -a` and `cat /etc/os-release` say 20.04.6. And software-updater wants to update to 20.04.2. What's going on there?

Answer (score 66):

Use the following commands to get more details:

1. `cat /etc/*release*`
2. `uname -a`

Comment: i like this answer better than the accepted one

Comment: Add `cat /proc/version` and it covers every release I've found over the years.  I've never seen a case where `/proc/version` wasn't helpful, but I've seen cases where one or both of the above don't help (can't remember which but most likely embedded systems.)

Answer (score 9):

There are a ton of answers but I'm looking for more generic. AFAI am concerned the following works on most of systems.

```
cat /etc/os-release
```

Example output:

```
sh-4.4$ cat /etc/os-release                                                                                                                                                                           
NAME=Fedora                                                                                                                                                                                           
VERSION="26 (Twenty Six)"                                                                                                                                                                             
ID=fedora                                                                                                                                                                                             
VERSION_ID=26                                                                                                                                                                                         
PRETTY_NAME="Fedora 26 (Twenty Six)"                                                                                                                                                                  
ANSI_COLOR="0;34"                                                                                                                                                                                     
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:fedoraproject:fedora:26"                                                                                                                                                             
HOME_URL="https://fedoraproject.org/"                                                                                                                                                                 
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"                                                                                                                                                         
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Fedora"                                                                                                                                                                      
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=26                                                                                                                                                                    
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Fedora"                                                                                                                                                                       
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=26                                                                                                                                                                     
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL=https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Legal:PrivacyPolicy
```

Comment: This will work on Linux distros that use systemd.  For older versions of those distros that don't use systemd, this won't work (e.g. RHEL 6), and for distros that don't use systemd at all this won't work.  The [second most voted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/193559/135943) will cat this file anyway, so there's no reason not to prefer that more general command.

Answer (score 6):

Use `cat /proc/version`

**Result:**

```
Linux version 3.14.27-100.fc19.x86_64 (mockbuild@bkernel02.phx2.fedoraproject.org) (gcc version 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-7) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Wed Dec 17 19:36:34 UTC 2014
```

I believe this works for most distros, and provides a more concise answer than `cat /etc/*release*` and more complete answer than `uname -a`.  However, use of `/proc` for things other than processes is now eschewed, so maybe it'll disappear someday.

Comment: This worked for me

Comment: On Apline 3.10.4 this returned something unexpected: `Linux version 4.19.76-linuxkit (root@d203b39a3d78) (gcc version 8.3.0 (Alpine 8.3.0)) #1 SMP Thu Oct 17 19:31:58 UTC 2019`

Comment: @b01 Thanks for the input.  At least it got the Alpine part correct. ;-)  Where did 3.10.4 come from, `uname -a`?  It's sad that there is no single correct answer!

Comment: I learned this while writing a tool that did a survey of connected systems which were embedded Linux running on various brands and models of storage servers.  It was the only command I found that returned something useful in every case, and since then I've never seen it not be useful, even on BusyBox-based distros.

Comment: @JeffLearman I was using a Go Lang Alpine Docker image of `1.13-alpine-3.10` and wanted to know the bug release number. I ended up trying quite a few of these answers to see which worked and not.

Comment: `/proc/version` tells the kernel version, including the compiler used to compile it. While the distribution name may appear in the compiler version (as in all examples here), it's hard to turn that into the release version of the distribution if that's what one wants. (And while the question doesn't exactly say that, a lot of the answers and comments here seem to assume that's at least part of what is meant.) The kernel version can be determined with `uname`, which also has the upside that it works on other systems too, not just Linux.

Comment: @ilkkachu - Unfortunately, `uname -a` returned unhelpful information on many embedded systems.  It's the first thing I tried, and probably is the best thing to try first.  But thanks for pointing out that /proc/version can be misleading.

Answer (score 5):

You should look into the `uname` command.

I have to deal with a large parc of heterogenous machines. `uname -a` is usually my first reflex when I log in.

Answer (score 5):

To combine some ideas here:

`cat /etc/*_version /etc/*-release && uname -a`

Should get you want you need on any distribution.

Comment: To those who are searching for which version is alpine running inside docker, this command works and produces following output: 

```cat: can't open '/etc/*_version': No such file or directory
3.14.2
NAME="Alpine Linux"
ID=alpine
VERSION_ID=3.14.2
PRETTY_NAME="Alpine Linux v3.14"
HOME_URL="https://alpinelinux.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.alpinelinux.org/"```

Answer (score 4):

Type in the command line:

```
uname -a
```

That'll give you all the information you seek.

Try also:

`man uname` to restrict the information

Answer (score 4):

For the Alpine distribution:

```
cat /etc/alpine-release
3.5.2
```

Answer (score 3):

`inxi` is a System Information Tool for Linux. It displays handy information concerning system hardware (hard disk, sound cards, graphic card, network cards, CPU, RAM, and more), together with system information about drivers, Xorg, desktop environment, kernel, GCC version(s), processes, uptime, memory, and a wide array of other useful information.

If `inxi` is not installed in your system, you can install it by:

```
$ sudo apt install inxi       [On Debian/Ubuntu/Linux Mint]
$ sudo yum install inxi       [On CentOs/RHEL/Fedora]
$ sudo dnf install inxi       [On Fedora 22+]
```

In manpage you can fine that `-S` option can be used to get host name, kernel, desktop environment (if in X/Wayland), distro.

```
% inxi -S
System:    Host: blueray-i5 Kernel: 5.4.0-53-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Cinnamon 4.6.7 Distro: Linux Mint 20 Ulyana
```

This can be used as a debugging, and/or forum technical support tool. So you might consider keeping it in your toolbelt.

Answer (score 1):

Centos 5 using file in `/etc/redhat-release`

Answer (score 1):

[whatami](https://github.com/open-mpi/mtt/blob/master/client/whatami/whatami) by Remy Evard at [Argonne National Lab](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/hs/software/systems/whatami/whatami-design.html). Install and run using these commands:

```
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/open-mpi/mtt/master/client/whatami/whatami && chmod a+x whatami
Resolving raw.githubusercontent.com... 151.101.116.133
Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com|151.101.116.133|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 24434 (24K) [text/plain]
Saving to: 'whatami'

whatami                                           100%[============================================================================================================>]  23.86K  --.-KB/s    in 0.02s   

2018-08-15 18:54:42 (1.49 MB/s) - 'whatami' saved [24434/24434]

$ ./whatami
darwin-macosx_10.11-x86_64
```

Comment: You might want to link to that tool or explain how you installed it, it's not on by default.

Answer (score 1):

A problem I found with the practical `uname-a` is that, in microsoft's wsl, it always returns something like (even inside docker containers!):

```
Linux d0b341b1f694 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Fri Apr 2 22:23:49 UTC 2021 x86_64 Linux
```

On the other hand, when  using `cat /etc/os-release` (or `cat /etc/*release*`), also in wsl, it returns the correct system of the container (or of the linux distro).

Answer (score -1):

For CentOs

```
$ cat /etc/centos-release
SHMZ release 6.6 (Final)
```