# How can I reliably get the operating system's name?

Tags: linux, distributions

Say I am logged into a remote system, how can I know what it's running? On most modern Linuxes (Linuces?), you have the `lsb_release` command:

```
$ lsb_release -ic    
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Codename:       debian
```

Which as far as I can tell just gives the same info as `/etc/lsb-release`. What if that file is not present? I seem to recall that the `lsb_release` command is relatively new so what if I have to get the OS of an older system?

In any case, `lsb` stands for `Linux Standard Base` so I am assuming it won't work on non-Linux Unices. As far as I know, there is no way of getting this information from `uname` so how can I get this on systems that do not use `lsb_release`?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6345/how-can-i-get-distribution-name-and-version-number-in-a-simple-shell-script?rq=1 for Linux. `uname -s` should be enough outside Linux (expect possibly for the BSDs).

Comment: Have you checked out `facter`? `facter operatingsystem` should do what you want on all the systems `facter` was made to work with.

Comment: @JosephR. looks good but is not installed by default.

Comment: I pasted the `facter` code that gets the operating system name on pastebin. Find it [here](http://pastebin.com/EDFJsNdj). It checks many different files to get the name reliably.

Comment: @JosephR. wow, that's a lot of files. I'll port that to bash when I get the chance, that should be portable enough. Thanks!

Comment: @terdon Glad I could help. Let us know how it goes :)

Comment: @JosephR. if you could expand that into an answer, something about there being various files etc, here's a list of them, I'd gladly accept it.

Comment: The best list by far is from linuxmafia: http://linuxmafia.com/faq/Admin/release-files.html for release files!!!!

Comment: a catch-all command that I find to be helpful when searching between large swaths of distros is just `source /etc/*-release`. also, `/etc/os-release` is a FreeDesktop standard that I believe distros are starting to adopt, so this may get easier in the future.

Comment: The words [Unix](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/242386?p=emailA4ekGEzuqgWpc&d=242386) and [Linux](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/251510?p=emailA4elVXGqDo3xw&d=251510) are not derived from Latin words. Therefore, the plurals are simply "Unixes" and "Linuxes" (although "Unix systems" and "Linux systems" probably sound nicer).

Comment: @PaddyLandau I know, but both Unices _and_ Unixen are used. This has more to do with convention than any kind of grammar.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

`lsb_release -a` is likely going to be your best option for finding this information out, and being able to do so in a consistent way.

#### History of LSB

The `lsb` in that command stands for the project [Linux Standards Base](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/lsb) which is an umbrella project sponsored by the [Linux Foundation](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/) to provide generic methods for doing basic kinds of things on various Linux distros.

The project is voluntary and vendors can participate within the project as just a user and also as facilitators of the various specifications around different modules that help to drive standardization within the different Linux distributions.

*excerpt from the [charter](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/lsb/about)*

> The LSB workgroup has, as its core goal, to address these two
>   concerns. We publish a standard that describes the minimum set of APIs
>   a distribution must support, in consultation with the major
>   distribution vendors. We also provide tests and tools which measure
>   support for the standard, and enable application developers to target
>   the common set. Finally, through our testing work, we seek to prevent
>   unnecessary divergence between the distributions.

#### Useful links related to LSB

- [LSB Charter](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/lsb/lsb-charter)
- [LSB Workgroup](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/lsb)
- [LSB Roadmap](http://linuxfoundation.org/en/LSB_Roadmap)
- [LSB Mailing List (current activity is here!)](http://lists.linuxfoundation.org/mailman/listinfo/lsb-discuss)
- [List of certified LSB products](https://www.linuxbase.org/lsb-cert/productdir.php?by_lsb)
- [LSB Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base)

#### Criticisms

There are a number of problems with LSB that make it problematic for distros such as Debian. The forced usage of RPM being one. See the [Wikipedia article for more on the matter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base#Reception).

#### Novell

If you search you'll possibly come across a fairly dated looking page titled: [Detecting Underlying Linux Distro](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/11251.html) from Novell. This is one of the few places I"ve seen an actual list that shows several of the major distros and how you can detect what underlying one you're using.

*excerpt*

```
Novell SUSE         /etc/SUSE-release
Red Hat             /etc/redhat-release, /etc/redhat_version
Fedora              /etc/fedora-release
Slackware           /etc/slackware-release, /etc/slackware-version
Debian              /etc/debian_release, /etc/debian_version,
Mandrake            /etc/mandrake-release
Yellow dog          /etc/yellowdog-release
Sun JDS             /etc/sun-release
Solaris/Sparc       /etc/release
Gentoo              /etc/gentoo-release
UnitedLinux         /etc/UnitedLinux-release
ubuntu              /etc/lsb-release
```

This same page also includes a handy script which attempts to codify for the above using just vanilla `uname` commands, and the presence of one of the above files.

**NOTE:** This list is dated but you could easily drop the dated distros such as Mandrake from the list and replace them with alternatives. This type of a script might be one approach if you're attempting to support a large swath of Solaris & Linux variants.

#### Linux Mafia

More searching will turn up the following page maintained on Linuxmafia.com, titled:  [/etc/release equivalents for sundry Linux (and other Unix) distributions](http://linuxmafia.com/faq/Admin/release-files.html). This is probably the most exhaustive list to date that I've seen. You could codify this list with a case/switch statement and include it as part of your software distribution.

In fact there is a script at the bottom of that page that does exactly that. So you could simply download and use the script as 3rd party to your software distribution.

*script*

```
#!/bin/sh
# Detects which OS and if it is Linux then it will detect which Linux
# Distribution.

OS=`uname -s`
REV=`uname -r`
MACH=`uname -m`

GetVersionFromFile()
{
    VERSION=`cat $1 | tr "\n" ' ' | sed s/.*VERSION.*=\ // `
}

if [ "${OS}" = "SunOS" ] ; then
    OS=Solaris
    ARCH=`uname -p` 
    OSSTR="${OS} ${REV}(${ARCH} `uname -v`)"
elif [ "${OS}" = "AIX" ] ; then
    OSSTR="${OS} `oslevel` (`oslevel -r`)"
elif [ "${OS}" = "Linux" ] ; then
    KERNEL=`uname -r`
    if [ -f /etc/redhat-release ] ; then
        DIST='RedHat'
        PSUEDONAME=`cat /etc/redhat-release | sed s/.*\(// | sed s/\)//`
        REV=`cat /etc/redhat-release | sed s/.*release\ // | sed s/\ .*//`
    elif [ -f /etc/SuSE-release ] ; then
        DIST=`cat /etc/SuSE-release | tr "\n" ' '| sed s/VERSION.*//`
        REV=`cat /etc/SuSE-release | tr "\n" ' ' | sed s/.*=\ //`
    elif [ -f /etc/mandrake-release ] ; then
        DIST='Mandrake'
        PSUEDONAME=`cat /etc/mandrake-release | sed s/.*\(// | sed s/\)//`
        REV=`cat /etc/mandrake-release | sed s/.*release\ // | sed s/\ .*//`
    elif [ -f /etc/debian_version ] ; then
        DIST="Debian `cat /etc/debian_version`"
        REV=""

    fi
    if [ -f /etc/UnitedLinux-release ] ; then
        DIST="${DIST}[`cat /etc/UnitedLinux-release | tr "\n" ' ' | sed s/VERSION.*//`]"
    fi

    OSSTR="${OS} ${DIST} ${REV}(${PSUEDONAME} ${KERNEL} ${MACH})"

fi

echo ${OSSTR}
```

**NOTE:** This script should look familiar, it's an up to date version of the Novell one!

#### Legroom script

Another method I've seen employed is to roll your own script, similar to the above Novell method but making use of LSB instead. This article titled: [Generic Method to Determine Linux (or UNIX) Distribution Name](http://legroom.net/2010/05/05/generic-method-determine-linux-or-unix-distribution-name), shows one such method.

```
# Determine OS platform
UNAME=$(uname | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]")
# If Linux, try to determine specific distribution
if [ "$UNAME" == "linux" ]; then
    # If available, use LSB to identify distribution
    if [ -f /etc/lsb-release -o -d /etc/lsb-release.d ]; then
        export DISTRO=$(lsb_release -i | cut -d: -f2 | sed s/'^\t'//)
    # Otherwise, use release info file
    else
        export DISTRO=$(ls -d /etc/[A-Za-z]*[_-][rv]e[lr]* | grep -v "lsb" | cut -d'/' -f3 | cut -d'-' -f1 | cut -d'_' -f1)
    fi
fi
# For everything else (or if above failed), just use generic identifier
[ "$DISTRO" == "" ] && export DISTRO=$UNAME
unset UNAME
```

This chunk of code could be included into a system's `/etc/bashrc` or some such file which would then set the environment variable `$DISTRO`.

#### gcc

Believe it or not another method is to make use of `gcc`. If you query the command `gcc --version` you'll get the distro that gcc was built for, which is invaribly the same as the system it's running on.

*Fedora 14*

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.5.1 20100924 (Red Hat 4.5.1-4)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

*CentOS 5.x*

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

*CentOS 6.x*

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

*Ubuntu 12.04*

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

#### TL;DR;

So which one should I use? I would tend to go with `lsb_release -a` for any Linux distributions that I would frequent (RedHat, Debian, Ubuntu, etc.). For situations where you're supporting systems that don't provide `lsb_release` I'd roll my own as part of the distribution of software that I'm providing, similar to one of the above scripts.

#### UPDATE #1: Follow-up with SuSE

In speaking with @Nils in the comments below it was determined that for whatever reason, SLES11 appeared to drop LSB from being installed by default. It was only an optional installation, which seemed counter for a package that provides this type of key feature.

So I took the opportunity to contact someone from the OpenSuSE project to get a sense of why.

*excerpt of email*

```
Hi Rob,

I hope you don't mind me contacting you directly but I found your info here: 
https://en.opensuse.org/User:Rjschwei. I participate on one of the StackExchange 
sites, Unix & Linux and a question recently came up regarding the best option 
for determining the underlying OS.

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92199/how-can-i-reliably-get-the-operating-systems-name/92218?noredirect=1#comment140840_92218

In my answer I suggested using lsb_release, but one of the other users mentioned 
that this command wasn't installed as part of SLES11 which kind of surprised me. 
Anyway we were looking for some way to confirm whether this was intentionally 
dropped from SLES or it was accidental.

Would you know how we could go about confirming this one way or another?

Thanks for reading this, appreciate any help and/or guidance on this.

-Sam Mingolelli
http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7453/slm
```

*Here's Rob's response*

```
Hi,

On 10/01/2013 09:31 AM, Sam Mingo wrote:
- show quoted text -

lsb_release was not dropped in SLES 11. SLES 11 is LSB certified. However, it 
is not installed by default, which is consistent with pretty much every other
distribution. The lsb_release command is part of the lsb-release package.

At present almost every distribution has an entry in /etc such as 
/etc/SuSE-release for SLES and openSUSE. Since this is difficult for ISVs and 
others there is a standardization effort going on driven by the convergence to 
systemd. The standard location for distribution information in the future will 
be /etc/os-release, although Ubuntu will probably do something different.

HTH,    
Robert

--  Robert Schweikert                           MAY THE SOURCE BE WITH YOU    
SUSE-IBM Software Integration Center                   LINUX    
Tech Lead    
Public Cloud Architect
```

Comment: Note: Just did a quick check on machines with AIX and SunOS. They don't seem to have lsb_release installed (and after all, this is Unix not Linux stack). Problem with gcc is that some ppl now start using clang. Also you can never be sure which gcc was used to build (on systems I work with there are at least few versions on each).

So my vote goes to Python solution as it seems to be installed now everywhere by default.

Comment: @elmo - yes LSB is Linux Standard Base, so I wouldn't expect either AIX or SunOS to have it. My experience with SunOS is 15+ years, and the majority of vendors whose software I dealt with would usually provide there own shell script similar to the ones I referenced above. Until Solaris 11, Python was not an option. And this is what makes it a difficult nut to crack. If you provide software that needs to run on Solaris 9, 10, 11, AIX, and a couple of Linux distros (SUSE, Ubntu, and RHEL) what do you do? Python is not an option, so you're left with a hand coded shell script.

Comment: @elmo - gcc though, an option, doesn't appear to be that appealing to me either. It seems wrought with too many problems, I was demonstrating it merely as an option.

Comment: @elmo - look at the code behind that function, http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/platform.py#l259. Big surprise it's using LSB!

Comment: @slm: I have access to machine with SunOS 5.10 (which I assume is 10 in your list - I am not that familiar with version numbers/conventions of Sun) and it does have a Python. I have access to machine with AIX 7 and it does have Python. Linux machines obviously have it also. So still Python looks like most portable choice.
As for Sun below 10 I am not sure why it wouldn't allow Python to be installed (admittedly current install is lacking i.e. ncurses and ctypes, so who knows).

As for Python using LSB it is not surprising at all for Linux if it is default approach.

Comment: @elmo - Yeah SunOS is different than Solaris, SunOS predates Solaris so I'm inclined to think you mean Solaris. The numbers are typically 2.9, 2.10, 2.11, people typically drop the 2., and simply call it 10. My point is that Python can be installed but in hardened production systems often times isn't for a variety of reasons. Though true it can be installed, when shipping software one can't guarantee that it will be there, and asking customers to install Python is one more requirement that you can save them.

Comment: `lsb_release` is not available on SLES11.

Comment: @Nils - is it installed? I think the package is `lsb`. http://linux.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/SuSE/2008-07/msg02304.html

Comment: @Nils - I don't think it's installed, this blog post clearly shows someone running it on SLES11, http://www.dizwell.com/2011/03/15/peas-n-pods/ (in comments).

Comment: @sterz what makes you think it's buggy? That's normal output.

Comment: @slm Interesting. I will check this. Possibly it is not installed by default (which seems to be strange). Other postings also show versions of SLES where it did not work.

Comment: @Nils - which postings? When I googled I found several that showed lsb_release output on SLES.

Comment: `lsb_release` is part of the lsb-release rpm in SLES11. It is not installed by default - so it will only work if installed. So not reliable for all Linuxes.

Comment: @Nils - I disagree, that's more a matter of who setup the system. Most enterprise + corporate servers/desktops would be deployed with this package installed and others.

Comment: I just checked our default-autoyast-profile for SLES: we did not exclude lsb or lsb_release. The base-pattern includes minimal+X11+base so this does not seem to include those packages. I would call this a enterprise server policy. If someone likes to, he/she can include these packages by default, but you can not gurantee that they exist unless you are in power to do so.

Comment: @Nils - that very much surprises me. I would expect a venerable package like this to be included. I wonder if it's a SLES vs. SLED type of an issue? I would still hold that this package should've been included with SLES and that it missing is an oversight. I've worked with CAD vendors in the past (Mentor, Synospsy, etc.) and that package was used for a variety of the installers as well as wrapper scripts that would check for the type of box, prior to running. We used this software on RH primarily but there were instances of SuSE (old versions by today's standards).

Comment: Yes - this seems to contradict the goals of the lsb-project. So if SuSE is member of that project someone should stamp on their feet.

Comment: @Nils - I also find it odd that one of the board members of OpenSuSE is part of the LSB working group. I might drop them a n email to see it was intentional or otherwise.

Comment: @Nils - sent an email to the board member that claims to be on the LSB working group, see what he says on the matter.

Comment: SLES is not OpenSuSE - so this might be intentional (but not good for profit either).

Comment: @Nils - yeah I figured it was a starting point.

Comment: @Nils - Rob responded, I've added the email exchange to my answer. LMK you thoughts.

Comment: I'm torn.  On the one hand, I love this answer for its amazing detail.  On the other, it's really hard to notice that it's about anything besides LSB, to the point where there's hestiation to call (e.g.) http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/293898/3629 a duplicate question.  With a little reorganization I think it could be a great canonical answer to the question.

Comment: Amazon Linux uses `/etc/system-release`. It also has the multi-line `/etc/os-release` with more details, as well as `/etc/issue`.

Comment: The best source I've found is the text file `/proc/version`.  Unfortunately the results aren't easily parsed to provide a clear distro name (which is also true of the '/etc' files).  `/proc/version` was available  in every case I've tried, which is not true of any `/etc` files.

Answer (score 19):

Since you probably won't be able to install `facter` on a remote server, you can mimic what it does to find the OS name. The Ruby code for the `operatingsystem` fact can be found [here on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/EDFJsNdj). Basically, it looks through the different `*-release` files and others to determine the OS name.

Some of the files it looks at:

```
/etc/debian_version
/etc/gentoo-release
/etc/fedora-release
/etc/mandriva-release
/etc/mandrake-release
/etc/meego-release
/etc/arch-release
/etc/oracle-release
/etc/enterprise-release
/etc/ovs-release
/etc/vmware-release
/etc/redhat-release
/etc/SuSE-release
/etc/bluewhite64-version
/etc/slamd64-version
/etc/slackware-version
/etc/alpine-release
/etc/system-release
/etc/centos-release
```

I'm sorry if you find duplicates in this list, I produced it quickly with `grep`. Should be fairly easy (albeit a bit tedious) to port this to a POSIX shell script.

Comment: "I'm sorry if you find duplicates in this list, I produced it quickly with grep." `... | uniq`?

Comment: @new123456 Right. Thanks. The key word here is "quickly" :)

Comment: Sorry about unaccepting this but @slm's answer is just too comprehensive to ignore :).

Comment: @terdon No worries. It's your question :)

Comment: what about /etc/os-release ?

Comment: @new123456 Technically, that should be `... | sort -u`. `uniq` only finds adjacent unique elements.

Comment: Add `/proc/release` to your list of sources.  I find it to be available even when none of the above are, and it's a lot easier to remember.

Comment: @JeffLearman I just checked and there's no `/proc/release` on my Arch box.

Comment: @JosephR.  Oops!  It's `/proc/version` not  `/proc/release`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

In case you have `python` installed (doesn't matter whether Python 3 or Python 2), you can find out the distribution name *without reinventing the wheel*:

```
python -c "import platform;print(platform.linux_distribution()[0])"
```

Comment: If you are tempted to use this option make sure your OS is supported: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/platform.py#l259. If not you can add more to the list: https://coderwall.com/p/cwrenq

Comment: This will not work with ancient Linux distributions.  For example: SuSE 7.0 had Python 1.5.2 and the platform module has been added not before the advent of Python 2.3 in 2003 ;-)

Answer (score 6):

`/etc/issue` should contain the release information.  I am fairly certain I've seen it on Solaris systems.  Here is the file from a modern Debian system:

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 7 \n \l

$
```

/etc/issue is also mentioned in the [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#ETCHOSTSPECIFICSYSTEMCONFIGURATION) (which isn't solely for Linux systems), although it is "optional."

Comment: Ah, that's a good suggestion, +1. It might not always work though `The  file  /etc/issue is a text file which contains a message or system identification to be printed before the  login  prompt.` It seems to be up to the sysadmin to write whatever he/she desires.

Comment: `/etc/issue` is completely unreliable. (I've see systems in version X.Y with an `/etc/issue` banner saying they were Y.Z following bad patch management. It can contain absolutely anything.)

Comment: It is recommended to fill that file with. legal stuff like who is allowed to login.

Comment: Recommended by security guidelines and auditors. There was once a case at law where a hacker came away without punishment, because there was WELCOME in /etc/issue

Comment: @drewbenn the man page says what I quoted in my first comment, there is nothing there about its needing to contain the system info. It just often does.

Comment: [Here is a good one with many further links and related law-stuff.](https://coderwall.com/p/lfdgaa)

Comment: This also works on a Raspberry Pi (and with the exact same output on the Raspberry Pi I tried it on).

Answer (score 6):

You can't reliably get the distro name from a single command across all distros.  Some are available via /etc/*-release and others are available via the 'lsb-release' command.

Comment: Thanks but neither is a help when it comes to Unix or any other non-Linux *nix.

Answer (score 4):

I used this shell command to get a string indicating Linux distribution:

```
for f in $(find /etc -type f -maxdepth 1 \( ! -wholename /etc/os-release ! -wholename /etc/lsb-release -wholename /etc/\*release -o -wholename /etc/\*version \) 2> /dev/null); do echo ${f:5:${#f}-13}; done;
```

this command is based on answers of Joseph R. and slm.

It just seeks for files like /etc/{osname}-release or /etc/{osname}_version and prints particular os name.

It worked in

- CentOS (centos)
- RedHat (redhat)
- Debian (debian)
- Arch (arch)
- OpenSUSE (OpenSUSE)
- Fedora (fedora)
- Ubuntu (debian)

Comment: Wouldn't `for f in /etc/*{_version,...*-release}; do [ -f "$f" ] && echo ${f:5:${#f}-13} ; done` work equally well on all of them? I don't understand why you would first `find` all files in `/etc`.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, terdon, but your command gives 0 lines in at least Cent OS and Fedora

Comment: http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/os-release.html
for FAQ

Comment: I've always liked: ```grep -Eh -- "DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION=|PRETTY_NAME=" /etc/*{_version,*-release} 2>/dev/null | cut -d= -f2 | tr -d "\"" | sort -u```

Answer (score 2):

Use `/etc/os-release`:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.10 (Cosmic Cuttlefish)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.10"
VERSION_ID="18.10"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=cosmic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=cosmic
```

The reasons are well explained in a FAQ by a link http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/os-release.html gratuitously provided by [@weberjn](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/78693/weberjn) in [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92199/how-can-i-reliably-get-the-operating-systems-name#comment633533_128470). I just list here one argument against using the `lsb_release` which is so far the top upvoted answer from 2013.

> **There's already the lsb_release tool for this, why don't you just use that?** Well, it's a very strange interface: a shell script you have to invoke (and hence spawn asynchronously from your C code), and it's not written to be extensible. It's an optional package in many distributions, and nothing we'd be happy to invoke as part of early boot in order to show a welcome message. (In times with sub-second userspace boot times we really don't want to invoke a huge shell script for a triviality like showing the welcome message). The lsb_release tool to us appears to be an attempt of abstracting distribution checks, where standardization of distribution checks is needed. It's simply a badly designed interface. In our opinion, it has its use as an interface to determine the LSB version itself, but not for checking the distribution or version.

Comment: Thanks, but the accepted answer already addresses this in the quote in the end which explains that `/etc/os-release` is going to become more standard. However, that file isn't always there on all systems which is why the accepted answer gives more portable alternatives. Also, I don't know why you're mentioning C code, the question isn't about invoking anything from C.

Comment: @terdon I am just curious what are those systems in 2018 where `/etc/os-release` is absent? I guess that their user base is miserable compared to systems where `lsb_release` is not shipped by default. At least I couldn't use your accepted answer on Fedora. As for C comment, it is not my, but a quote from `systemd` 0pointer.de link that I provided.

Comment: Yes, I know it's not yours, I was just wondering why you felt that a quote about C code was relevant. And as far as I know, `os-release` is mostly or exclusively a Linux thing. It seems to be [defined](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/os-release.html) by FreeDesktop.org, so maybe some Unix flavors also use it, but I doubt you'll find it in most or in embedded systems or any non-GUI system etc. Finally, don't forget that many places still use very old machines for reasons of stability.

Comment: The quote is about `lsb_release` and you can replace C with Go and get the same argument. The overhead of running `lsb_release` is much higher from both security and performance points than just parsing static file. I don't believe in very old machines providing stability. Heartbleed and friends should have taken them away long ago, so just use `/etc/os-release`

Answer (score 1):

[SNMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol) is an ubiquitous enough protocol so as to be found in many different kinds of GNU/Linux distributions and UNIX systems.

The [`system.sysDescr.0`](http://www.monfox.com/dsnmp/mibs/SNMPv2-MIB.html#sysDescr.status) object in the [SNMPv2-MIB](http://www.oidview.com/mibs/0/SNMPv2-MIB.html) can help you find out which OS you are contacting, provided there's an SNMP daemon running in the target system:

> Description
>
> A textual description of the entity.  This value should
>   include the full name and version identification of the
>   system's hardware type, software operating-system, and
>   networking software.
>
> Status:    current
>
> Access:    read-only

The [`snmpget(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/snmpget) manpage explains how to retrieve this value with examples.

Comment: Drawback is that this is a static string that is not automatically maintained.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no common way to do so, we defined an release-string via the snmp exec-command.

The task of that command is to print out distro and the current major/minor version of the os.

On RH and clones we parse /etc/redhat-release, on SuSe SuSe-release...

Comment: Who is 'we'? And how about Unix?

Comment: @terdon we is our team at work. On Unix you can do the same if the corresponding extension is compiled into snmpd.

Comment: Ah, I thought you were a part of some standards group :)

Comment: @terdon You start developing site-standards when you have to manage more than 80 servers. We developed this method so we could monitor wether the os is outdated (EoL minor or even major number)

Answer (score 1):

From what I've managed to glean from this thread you should be able to get the info from damn-near any system using:

```
if which lsb_release &>> /dev/null; then
    lsb_release -a
elif [ -r /etc/issue ]; then
    cat /etc/issue
else
    ls /etc/ | grep -e '[_-]release$' -e '[_-]version$' | xargs -I % -n 1 cat /etc/%
fi
```

Comment: don't parse output of ls!

Comment: @heinrich5991 why not?

Comment: Technically, he isn't parsing the output of `ls`. He's **lexing** the output of `ls`. But yeah... This is wrong because `/etc/issue` is completely unreliable. Completely, entirely, totally unreliable. Also, your assumption that no one might put a non-os-related file ending in 'release' or 'version' is unwise.

Comment: @ParthianShot So mainly you want to complain about the second and third levels of fallback in the case that the *more reliable options* are not available?

Comment: @Sammitch `more reliable options` Well, for one thing, there's only one option. So even assuming I agreed with your assumption that it's more reliable (which I don't), let's not start pluralizing things. Second, if someone actually used your solution, and it utterly failed half the time, they wouldn't be consoled by the fact that it was failing in an "else if". None of my systems have `lsb` installed by default.

Answer (score 1):

If a situation called for it,  you could find out remotely using snmpwalk [or the SNMP protocal in general]. An example is below:

```
snmpwalk -Os -c <snmp community string> -v1 <hostname> sysDescr.0
```

OUPUT:
sysDescr.0 = STRING: Linux example.hostname.com 2.6.32-358.23.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Sat Sep 14 05:32:37 EDT 2013 x86_64

The key to the reliability is whether SNMP is setup correctly in your environment, all hosts have snmp running with proper community strings setup.

Comment: What's `snpwalk`? Where can I find it? Also, that just prints "Linux", no distribution information (which is what I want, `uname` can give me `Linux`). Does it work on non-Linux OSs? On UNIX say, or BSD or OSX?

Comment: snmpwalk is a Linux command line utility. It doesn't just print "Linux" it also prints the kernel version which is really the only thing you need. If SNMP is configured on your other hosts, whether it is UNIX, BSD, OSX, snmpwalk will work as it is a standard (v1|v2c|v3), and it will even work across the water on Windows hosts as well. See also snmpget or snmpgetnext.

Comment: Sounds good but could you please [edit] your answer and explain where we can find it. It's not int he Debian repos for example. Also, please explain what it gives that `uname -a` doesn't and how it can tell me the name of the distribution which is what this question is about. Anyway, even assuming it can return this info, seeing as it's a non-standard utility and needs to be installed, I'm not sure it would be useful here. The idea is to log on to a remote system and find out the OS (including distribution if it's Linux).

Comment: `it also prints the kernel version which is really the only thing you need` But... that's the whole point of this question. If that was really all you needed, you could just use `uname -a`. The kernel is an important part of an operating system, but it's not the entire operating system. Filesystem layout and userland utilities (e.g. package manager) matter.