# How to inspect group permissions of a file

Tags: bash, permissions, ls, stat

I would like to inspect group permissions of a file from a bash script. Specifically, I need to check whether a file has the group writeable bit on.

That's it. Simple as that. However:

1. I also need this to be portable.
2. `test -w <file` won't tell me whether it's group writeable.
3. The output of `ls -ld` is nice for humans, but not so sure about scripts. Technically I could parse output such as `drwxrwxr-x` to extract the group bits, but this seems brittle.
4. The interface for `stat` is completely incompatible between OS X and other systems.
5. `find <file> -perm ...` can't possibly be the answer?

Comment: Do you need to check the group permission bit, or do you need to check if a specific group has write permissions? The group (or the user) could have write permission through an ACL.

Comment: Just the group permission bit. No specific group is relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up `ls`-parsing:

```
is_group_writable() {
  local ls="$(ls -ld "$1")"
  [ "${ls:5:1}" = "w" ]
}
```

I'm grateful for @slm's extensive answer, but none of the other methods are as straightforward. The `stat` method would require me to write at least two different invocations to cover OS X, and even after that it returns the octal representation which I still have to apply arithmetic to. The Perl method is OK but requires me to start an interpreter for such a simple task, and I would like to keep it simple and using only posix utils.

Comment: You're using bash, not just POSIX. In POSIX: `perms=$(ls -ld -- "$1"); perms=${perms%% *}; case $perms in ?????w????) …`

Answer (score 10):

#### Method #1 - stat

You could use the `stat` command to get the permissions bits. `stat` is available on most Unixes (OSX, BSD, not AIX from what I can find). This should work on most Unixes, except OSX & BSD from what I can find.

```
$ stat -c "%a" <file>
```

#### Example

```
$ ls -l a
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 155 Oct  6 14:16 afile.txt
```

Use this command:

```
$ stat -c "%a" afile.txt
664
```

And use a simple `grep` to see if the groups permissions mode is a 6 or 7.

```
$ stat -c "%a" afile.txt | grep ".[67]."
```

For OSX and BSD you'd need to use this form of `stat`, `stat -f` (or perhaps `stat -x`), and parse accordingly. Since the options to `stat` are different you could wrap this command in an `lsb_release -a` command and call the appropriate version based on the OS. Not ideal but workable. Realize that `lsb_release` is [only available for Linux distros](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92199/how-can-i-reliably-get-the-operating-systems-name) so [another alternative](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9997/resources-for-portable-shell-programming) would need to be devised for testing other Unix OSes.

#### Method #2 - find

I think this command might serve you better though. I makes use of `find` and the `printf` switch.

#### Example

```
$ find a -prune -printf '%m\n'
664
```

#### Method #3 - Perl

Perl might be a more portable way to do this depending on the OSes you're trying to cover.

```
$ perl -le '@pv=stat("afile.txt"); printf "%04o", $pv[2] & 07777;'
0664
```

**NOTE:** The above makes use of Perl's `stat()` function to query the filesystem bits.

You can make this more compact by forgoing using an array, `@pv`, and dealing with the output of `stat()` directly:

```
$ perl -le 'printf "%04o", (stat("a"))[2] & 07777;'
0664
```

Comment: I think you missed his point 4. The `stat` command varies widely among different systems and is not portable.

Comment: @jordanm - thanks I saw it, was looking for an alternative. I think `find . -printf` can do it but can't determine if it's available on OSX' find.

Comment: I am not sure either, I know it's not POSIX.

Comment: I couldn't find it referenced in the POSIX2008 guide either, so I'm inclined to agree. I'm not sure of any other methods. I think you have to bite the bullet here and detect which OS and call the approp. command, would seem to be the best approach.

Comment: I couldn't think of a method using a standard shell utility either. That's why my answer uses perl.

Comment: @jordanm - great minds. I was working on a perl solution too 8-)

Comment: `lsb_release -a` is a Linux-only command.  Not that surprising since LSB stands for Linux Standard Base.  If all the platforms he is working on have `stat`, it would be possible to detect which version it is.  On OpenBSD at least, while `stat -x` could work, `stat -f` seems to be a lot closer to the `stat -c` you were using.

Comment: @kurtm - Yup know all about `lsb_release`. I've added links to another U&L Q&A about that. You could run multiple `stat` commands and based on the results, determine if you're on a platform that supports one switch vs. another. Added info on diff. vers. of stat, thanks.

Comment: @slm: Thanks for the plethora of approaches. I ended up writing and picking my own answer since I wanted to go with the least amount of code, and no extra language interpreter if I can avoid it.

Comment: This is old, but shouldn't the pattern in Method #1 include '2'? So it would be a grep for ".[267].".

Comment: @NoahSpurrier - No, I don't think so. He was looking to find out if the write bit was enabled or not. The `grep` will detect if it's on when there's either a 6 or a 7 in the middle of the 3 digits that is returned via `stat`. A 2 would denote that it was read only. If the `grep` for my pattern returns nothing, that would mean that it was potentially a 2 or 0.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `perl`, which will be portable everywhere `perl` is available. It's tough to find a unix system without it. Here is an example of how it can be integrated into a shell script:

```
if perl -e 'use Fcntl ":mode"; exit( ((stat("file.txt"))[2] & S_IWGRP) >> 3)'; then
    echo "file is group writable"
else
    echo "file is not group witeable"
fi
```

Similar `perl` examples can be found in the [stat perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
FILE="filename";G=$(stat -c '%a' ${FILE} | cut -c2);
if [ $G -gt 5 ];then   echo "Group write is set on ${FILE}";fi
```

All standard Unix/Linux tools.

I suppose it's POSSIBLE to have group write, but not group read.  In that possibility, it would be either a case statement 2|3|6|7)  or a grep '[2|3|6|7]'