# find files with -perm and change perms

Tags: permissions, find, chmod

I need to find all files in a directory where “other” have permissions to read, write, or execute, and I need to apply those permission to “group”.

Example: if `file1` has `rwxr--rw-`, this would change it to `rwxrw-rw-`.

But in the case that “group” has permissions but “other” doesn’t, I need to leave it as is.

I need to use one command for this with no pipes.

Any tips you can help me with?

Comment: "One command with no pipes" sounds like a homework assignment requirement. Is that it, or is this a real-life problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for the `-perm /mode` form of the command (*"Any  of  the  permission bits mode are set for the file"*) rather than the `-perm -mode` form (*"All of the permission bits mode are set for the file"*)

Comment: it is indeed an asignment @l0b0, as i stated, ido not want the answer, i only want tips that might point me in the right direction.

Comment: @steeldriver thanks, i will look into it right now.

Comment: @julie Hint: `chmod` with "symbolic" modes (see [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod)) will allow you to surgically set individual bits in a file's mode, without affecting other bits.

Comment: There's always the option of doing `chmod g+o` on all files without checking if that's needed first (would have the side effect of updating the ctime though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In hint form, since this is an assignment:

We can check whether a specific group and other permission is *different* with the following `find` syntax:

```
\( -perm -o=PERMISSION -not -perm -g=PERMISSION \)
```

Since there are eight different possibilities you'll need eight of these to match all differences.

Once you have these files you can use `-exec COMMAND {} \;` to run `COMMAND` for each file.

`chmod` is the command to change the permissions.

Now, how you'd actually copy the permissions from other to group without running [another command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/97648/3645) is a bit of a conondrum.

Comment: I found a way to isolate all files that have other permissions (any of the 7 possibilities, since if it have no perms nothing is changing in group). my issue is the chmod that i have to basicly tell, if other has r perm and groupe doesnt, give group r perm, and do the same for all seven possibilities. thanks you for your help anyway, because i used another way to do it, i didnt know i could do it youre way.

Comment: Thank you very much @l0b0 ! That helps alot

Comment: I'd be interested to know how you end up copying the permissions across within a single command.

Comment: I figured it all out, thanks to your help and @steeldriver but i dont want to send the answer here. is there a way to pm someone?

Comment: Not really, but you could always add another comment here once you've handed it in :)

Comment: Okey i will in a couple of days!

Comment: Note that `-not` is a GNUism. The standard equivalent is `!`.

Answer (score 0):

The command I used to solve my problem was :

```
find ./directory/ -perm /o=rwx -execdir chmod g+o {} +
```

Thanks again for the help, @l0b0 and @steeldriver!

Comment: It would appear that you are using two different accounts. Please consider contacting the administrators to [merge](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) them.