# How can I get my Linux distribution name and version using the command line ?

Tags: command-line, distributions

I have Linux Mint Version 7.1 Rebecca. What do I need to write in the command line in order to find this information. I tried uname -a , but I got informations about my computer name, Kernel Version etc. but not the name itself.

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92199/how-can-i-reliably-get-the-operating-systems-name