# How can I determine the OS within .bash_profile?

Tags: bash, osx

On my main machine, a MacBook Pro, I have a `.bash_profile` file that I'd like to use unaltered on my Dreamhost linux machine. However, there's a few lines that are only applicable to macOS, such as `alias mvim="/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/MacVim"`.

Is there a way in bash to test for whether it's running under macOS or Debian (or just not macOS) and only execute that above line, and a few others, when running under macOS? Whereas other questions here address how to find out which Linux distro is being used, here I only need to know if I'm running on macOS or Linux, and the solutions for knowing the Linux distro aren't available on macOS.

Comment: What does `uname -s` show on a Mac?  Under Linux, it returns `Linux`.

Comment: `Darwin`, so, that helps quite a bit, along with Julie's suggestion. ty

Comment: @cat not in this case. The question there and the answers seem to revolve around which Linux distro is being used, whereas I needed to know only whether I'm working on Linux or macOS (Darwin). `uname` seems to be perfect for that.

Comment: @Chuck Oops, that question isn't the one I was looking for as a dupe. I swore we had a canonical "what's uname" etc question but I guess not

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if [[ $(uname -s) == Linux ]]
then
    doThis
else
    doThat
fi
```

Comment: Just in case someone doesn't see my comment above, using `if [[ $(uname -s) == Darwin ]]` in the first line will execute the `then` clause.

Comment: @Chuck:  Not sure what you mean.  I tried to remove the `then` and it didn't work.

Comment: I wasn't clear. I didn't mean to imply that `then` wasn't required, only that using `Darwin` works if you want then `then` clause to execute on macOS.

Comment: Note that `-s` seems to be superfluous. If no flags are provided, the `-s` is implied, so the `if` line can be `if [[ $(uname) == Darwin ]]`, which I've confirmed both with the man page and testing.

Comment: did you mean `if [[ "$(uname -s)" == "Linux" ]]; then...` ? (And if not, then why?)

Comment: @cat:  the quotes are not required.

Comment: Huh, and what happens if someone has the bright idea to make `uname -s` output `blah"blah"` or `]]; then :; fi; rm -rf / #` ?

Comment: @cat: `uname` is a built-in Unix command.  If someone is stupid enough to do that, they should expect lots of problems.

Comment: Evolution In Action, unix-style

Comment: +1 for me....  note some others: for AIX: "AIX",  For MacOS: "Darwin",  and for Solaris: "SunOS". I don't know for other systems (yet) but those would be nice to be included in the answer

Answer (score 11):

On OSX, `uname -s` returns `Darwin` (most Linux `uname` programs return `Linux`).

As a general rule (aside from personal use), `uname` has quirks for different systems.  In `autoconf`, scripts use `config.guess`, which provides consistent information.

For example in my Debian 7,

```
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

and in OSX *El Capitan*

```
x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0
```

You could use if-then-else statements in the shell, or a case-statement.  The latter are more easily maintained, e.g.,

```
case $(config.guess) in
*linux*)
    DoSomeLinuxStuff
    ;;
*apple-darwin*)
    DoSomeMacStuff
    ;;
esac
```

Many Linux distributions add information to the output of `uname`, but this is useful only on a case-by-case basis.  There is *no* standard for the information added.

For my Debian 7:

```
$ uname -v
#1 SMP Debian 3.2.81-1
```

while OSX is radically different:

```
$ uname -v
Darwin Kernel Version 15.5.0: Tue Apr 19 18:36:36 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3248.50.21~8/RELEASE_X86_64
```

Further reading:

- [config.guess](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=config.git;a=blob_plain;f=config.guess)

Comment: Thanks for the details, but while it sounds like `config.guess` is more robust than `uname`, for macOS, `uname` returns `Darwin`, and Linux won't return that no matter what, so that's sufficient for my needs. I suppose it's *possible* that a raw Darwin (no macOS GUI) will also return `Darwin`, I've never used such a system, only macOS, Linux, and (if I can't avoid it) Windows.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternate solution, you might try splitting your `.bash_profile` into a portable part and a system-specific part.

In your main `.bash_profile` add the following:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_profile_local ] ; then
    . ~/.bash_profile_local
fi
```

Then put any customizations that apply only to a given system into `.bash_profile_local` on that system.  If you have no customizations, you don't have to create the file.

Or, if you wanted to go even further and have pieces shared among some systems but not others, you could do a full-on SYSV-style rc.d directory.  In `.bash_profile`:

```
if [ -d ~/.bash_profile.d ] ; then
    for f in ~/.bash_profile.d/* ; do
        if [ -f "$f" ] ; then
            . "$f"
        fi
    done
fi
```

Then create a `.bash_profile.d` directory, and any files you put in there will be run as if they were part of your `.bash_profile`.

Comment: Thanks, @Jander, but I do like the simplicity of the accepted solution. The platform-specific lines are very few (4 or so), and are mostly just `alias` declarations like the example I gave (MacVim, Sage, etc.), although I'll probably change the MacVim alias into a function so I can stop having to type `mvim file &` and just type `mvim file`.