# On what Linux distributions can I rely on the presence of /etc/os-release?

Tags: linux, distributions

I'm trying to find a way to determine Linux distribution name and version that would work on most (or ideally, all) modern distributions. I noticed that `/etc/os-release` contains the info I need on the distributions I tried (CentOS, Debian), but how safe is it to rely on the presence of it? Commands such as `uname -a` don't really contain the same info, and `lsb_release` is apparently not present on e.g. minimal CentOS.

Is there a quick way to find out exactly what distros come with `/etc/os-release`? Moreover, is `/etc/os-release` guaranteed to contain `NAME`, `VERSION` and `PRETTY_NAME` fields?

Comment: Ubuntu, Debian, Arch for sure. Anyway I would omit detecting distro that way. Last time I need to distinguish distros I was checking a presence of particular package managers (i. e. pacman -> Arch, apt-get & no pacman -> either Ubuntu or Debian). It's kinda tricky task and I would also like to know whether there is a better solution.

Comment: One wonders why do you need to know the distribution name. This sounds like a case of [Browser detection](https://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/feature-detection-vs-browser-detection/) when you should be doing [Feature detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_detection_(computer_vision)).

Comment: @xDaizu I'm running scripts on remote hosts to pull various info about them.

Comment: @w128 in that case, can't you check if the "feature" (/etc/os-release) exists (and fallback to other methods if not) instead of relying in a static mutable list of distributions where it works?

Comment: @xDaizu falling back to "other methods" may involve extra work that may prove unnecessary if I can guarantee the simple solution proposed in the question to be reliable on the several major distros I need to support, so a mutable list of supported distros is fine in this case.

Comment: Relevant: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92199/22222

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Any system running systemd should have `/etc/os-release`, which is [specified](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/os-release.html) as part of systemd. Some systems without systemd might have it too (*e.g.* Debian 8 where systemd is optional but `/etc/os-release` is installed in all cases).

According to the specification, all fields are optional, and some have defaults ("Linux" for `NAME` and `PRETTY_NAME`).

You’ll find more background in the [`/etc/os-release` announcement](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/os-release).