# What Linux distro is the following one?

Tags: administration, distributions

I have to find out which Linux distribution is running on a server. From uname -a I have the following output:

```
$ uname -a
Linux lvmfacelifttap2b 3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP SUn Dec 11 12:25:18 EST 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I've tried googling but I couldn't find a match. Any help how to find out the distribution ?
Thanks

Comment: That's a kernel, not a distribution.

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92199/117549

Comment: run `cat /etc/*release`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.el7.
```

means Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7

Comment: That's the name in the kernel, anyway, which is a good hint, but certainly doesn't require a particular distribution around it.

Comment: It could also be CentOS. I think CentOS also has kernel's ending in `el`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now that I have access to the shell I can confirm it's a RHEL