# porting install scripts : can rpm replace apt?

Tags: shell-script, apt, yum, rpm, software-distribution

I have the following install script for ubuntu :

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade -y
sudo apt install jq
sudo apt autoclean -y
sudo apt autoremove
```

will the following work under fedora, red hat, mageia or other rpm-based distros

...or does the syntax have to change more?

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo rpm update
sudo rpm full-upgrade -y
sudo rpm install jq
sudo rpm autoclean -y
sudo rpm autoremove
```

also can I do something to the effect of the following? :

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $(command -v yum) ]
then
    sudo yum update
    sudo yum full-upgrade -y
    sudo yum install jq
    sudo yum autoclean -y
    sudo yum autoremove
else
    sudo rpm update
    sudo rpm full-upgrade -y
    sudo rpm install jq
    sudo rpm autoclean -y
    sudo rpm autoremove
fi
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`rpm` is mostly equivalent to `dpkg`, not `apt`; the `apt` equivalent is `yum` (on RHEL and CentOS up to release 7), or `dnf` (on Fedora, and RHEL and CentOS starting with release 8), or [`zypper` (on SuSE)](https://en.opensuse.org/Portal:Zypper). For your specific commands:

```
sudo dnf distro-sync
sudo dnf install jq
sudo dnf clean all
sudo dnf autoremove
```

or

```
sudo yum upgrade
sudo yum install jq
sudo yum clean all
```

(This works because `jq` is packaged under the same name in both cases. This isn’t always true; a given piece of software can be packaged under different names in different distributions or even different releases of a given distribution.)

See [the Pacman Rosetta](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Rosetta) and [the Ubuntu RHEL migration guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwitchingToUbuntu/FromLinux/RedHatEnterpriseLinuxAndFedora) for details.

You might want to look into configuration management tools instead, they will help you abstract the differences away (or at least, deal with them more robustly).

Your `if [ $(command -v yum) ]` test is flawed because `yum` can be installed on Debian derivatives (including Ubuntu); its presence doesn’t mean it’s the package manager. You should probably detect the running operating system and base your choice on that; see [How can I reliably get the operating system's name?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92199/86440) for details.

Comment: aw shucks package name can change? whyyyy?

Comment: who has dnf? redhat? and I assume yum is more towards mageia and fedora?

Comment: Because they’re different distribution, with different packaging practices, naming rules, etc.

Comment: `yum` is used in RHEL up to version 7, CentOS up to version 7, and probably other RPM-based distributions; `dnf` is used in Fedora, and RHEL 8 and later.

Comment: huh, fedora doesn't use yum?

Comment: No, it hasn’t for quite a while.

Comment: Even if another distribution uses the same package manager, it doesn't always mean that an application will be packaged under the same name or even exist. For example, there may or may not be a "firefox" package in your particular release of debian.

Comment: There is also [Zypper](https://en.opensuse.org/Portal:Zypper) from SuSE, which sadly has a bit of market share, especially around SAP.

Comment: @Morfildur yup, and the equivalent commands for Zypper are listed in the Pacman Rosetta.

Comment: @tatsu Package names do not only change between package managers, but even between distributions. Debian and Ubuntu for example both use ``apt``, but do not agree on all package names.

Comment: @allo thanks for the information. that is just insanity. I can't be the only one who thinks this. we must create an effort to unify names.

Comment: @tatsu You might find this educational: 
https://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: @Morfildur haha, yeah. although in this case I'm not advocating creating everything new, just knocking at doors and bugging people over exsisting repos.

Answer (score 5):

No, the options and arguments to `apt` and `yum` are different, so are package names in a lot of cases.

You also seem to be getting `rpm` and `yum` confused, `yum` is the equivalent of `apt`, `rpm` is the equivalent of `dpkg`. `dpkg` is the backend for `apt`, `rpm` is the backend for `yum`.

You will have to look at the `man` pages for both `apt` and `yum` to find the equivalent options. Alternativly you could look at a configuration management tool like `puppet` which will abstract a lot of OS differences between distros, but this may be overkill for what you're doing.