# E: Package 'sshpass' has no installation candidate(not able to install sshpass in linux)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmware, sshpass, packagekit

sudo apt-get install sshpass

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree... Done

Reading state information... Done

Package sshpass is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

[image: E: Package 'sshpass' has no installation candidate]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This question already exists: [Always asks are you root? failed to install sshpass in ubuntu. linux. i tried removing lock , updating but could not install](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/768837/always-asks-are-you-root-failed-to-install-sshpass-in-ubuntu-linux-i-tried-re)

Comment: No body has answered it

Comment: The right thing is to fix your original question (the comment there tells you exactly what information we need) and wait for reviewers to reopen it. It's true some users manage to bend the rules by deleting the old (closed) question and posting anew, sometimes they get away with this. But this makes sense if the new question is better than the old one. Your new question is not better than your old one. It will be treated alike, unless you improve it.

Comment: Like then what should I add ...like I am new to this platform and so I don't know what more should I do/add to solve my problem

Comment: The most important information is: what is the OS? [Tell us the exact version of it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/23833/108618) if you can.

Comment: It is Ubuntu but in virtual box version I can tell in sometime

Comment: (0) All relevant information shall be added to the question ([edit] the question), [highly preferably as text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/108618). (1) What is the output of `cat /etc/issue`? (2) Did you run `sudo apt-get update` before `sudo apt-get install …`? (3) What is the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`? Have you changed anything in this file?

Comment: 1)Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS \n \l

Comment: (0 again) All relevant information shall be added to the question.

Comment: 1)Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS \n \l  2) yes i did 3) i did not changed anything

Comment: This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.

Comment: Posting in comments is not "adding to the question"; [edit]ing the question and adding information to the question body is. Please take our short [tour] to see how the site is designed to work. Then edit the question and move information from your comments to the question.

Comment: You must have missed this link when I posted it for the first time, so again: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/108618).

Comment: but for now i have added will not from the next but now can you help me out!?

Comment: There is a bright side: you did add information, you are responding to comments, you are learning how the site works. Keep it up. Even with the images of text this question is significantly better than the old (deleted) one, I don't expect it to be closed as unclear. This does not mean you should stop improving it, but I wanted to let you know you're on the right track.

Comment: Note: in `sudo apt-get … && apt-get … && apt-get …` the `sudo` applies to the first `apt-get` only. The whole command will probably work as intended if you precede *each* `apt-get` with `sudo`. Maybe it will not solve the problem yet, but I'm sure it's the lack of `sudo` before the second `apt-get` that gave you `are you root?`.

Comment: still nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

the package you want is in your repos [jammy](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/sshpass), so you need to update ubuntu to find that package using sudo instead of just apt-get

Comment: The screenshots show `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install sshpass` so the lack of `sudo` isn’t the problem here.

Comment: Look at the last screenshot. He's doing `sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get install sshpass`. `sudo` stops being relevant after the first `&&` and I'm willing to bet that's what's fouling him up.

Comment: nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

`sshpass` is available from `universe` repository (already enabled in your sources.list):

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install sshpass
```

The last command should be:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade && sudo apt install sshpass
```

The first command is executed with `sudo`, but the commands after `&&` aren't. [@Shadur comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/768880/e-package-sshpass-has-no-installation-candidatenot-able-to-install-sshpass-i#comment1467843_768882)

Comment: still the same error