# Can't install dpkg on Linux 2.6.18

Tags: linux, software-installation, dpkg

I have a virtual machine that I am trying to use. It doesn't seem to have dpkg or apt-get, so I downloaded the source from http://packages.debian.org/sid/dpkg-dev.

If I run ./configure followed by make I get

```
$ make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/dbadmin/temp/dpkg-1.16.8'
Making all in lib
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/dbadmin/temp/dpkg-1.16.8/lib'
Making all in compat
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/dbadmin/temp/dpkg-1.16.8/lib/compat'
  CC     empty.o
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wvla"
make[3]: *** [empty.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/dbadmin/temp/dpkg-1.16.8/lib/compat'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/dbadmin/temp/dpkg-1.16.8/lib'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/dbadmin/temp/dpkg-1.16.8'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I tried 
$ ./configure --disable-compiler-warnings
$ make
to get ...

```
  CC     trigproc.o
  CC     update.o
  CCLD   dpkg
archives.o: In function `tar_writeback_barrier':
/home/dbadmin/temp/dpkg-1.16.8/src/archives.c:1139: undefined reference to `sync_file_range'
archives.o: In function `fd_writeback_init':
/home/dbadmin/temp/dpkg-1.16.8/src/archives.c:77: undefined reference to `sync_file_range'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dpkg] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/dbadmin/temp/dpkg-1.16.8/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/dbadmin/temp/dpkg-1.16.8'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This is my machine

```
$ uname -a
Linux server.name.domain.tld 2.6.18-194.26.1.el5xen #1 SMP Fri Oct 29 14:30:03 EDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

How should I go about getting a functional package manager on this?

**Update:**
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51)

Comment: If there is no apt/dpkg, you probably are not running a Debian derivative. Use the package manager appropriate for your OS.

Comment: @jordanm, how do I find out the OS flavor? I just have ssh access to the virtual machine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dpkg is designed to work on Debian and Debian-like distributions. It can be difficult to compile on other systems, and you wouldn't be able to use it effectively anyway. Also, a kernel version of 2.6.18 is ancient (I smell CentOS 5), only an older version of dpkg has a chance of working.

> gcc --version gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51)

So you have a Red Hat distribution: [RHEL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux) or a repackaging thereof such as CentOS. The basic package manipulation tool (the equivalent of dpkg) on Red Hat distributions is [rpm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPM_Package_Manager). The high-level package manipulation tool (the equivalent of apt-get) is [yum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow_dog_Updater,_Modified).

For more systematic ways of determining which distribution a Linux machine is running, see [How to write a script that effectively determines distro name?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23050/how-to-write-a-script-that-effectively-determines-distro-name). If you're lucky, `lsb-release -si` will give you the answer. Otherwise, look for indicative files such as `/etc/*release*` or `/etc/*version*`.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have all dependencies installed, in particular GCC?

`unrecognized command line option "-Wvla"` [sounds like you don't have GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2007-03/msg00775.html), or not a recent enough version.

What system are you running exactly (distribution, version, ...)?

PS: Why do you want to install dpkg on a non-debian / barebones Linux system, and not install Debian?

Comment: I have gcc 4.1.2. I gave the uname -a output. How do I get more information on the OS distribution? What package manager should I install on this machine?

Answer (score 1):

As it seems that use a Red Hat based system, the default package manager should be [`rpm`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPM_Package_Manager) and probably [`yum`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellowdog_Updater,_Modified) the corresponding user-frontend.

Please note, that any package you install need to fit to your system and to the other installed packages.