# How can I identify the variant of Unix/Linux from a shell?

Tags: shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get distribution name and version number in a simple shell script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6345/how-can-i-get-distribution-name-and-version-number-in-a-simple-shell-script)

Given a shell, how can I identify the variant of Unix/Linux that is running on a remote server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can also do **cat /etc/*-release** to see info about the distribution version and name.

```
$ cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12
DISTRIB_CODENAME=lisa
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 12 Lisa"
```

Source: [linuxg.net](http://linuxg.net/5-ways-to-find-out-what-linux-you-are-using/)

Comment: I think cat /etc/*-release* is better. Some distros (Crunchbang is an example) has longer file names.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried either of the following:

```
uname -a
```

or

```
cat /proc/version
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try :

```
cat /etc/issue
```

Maybe not all distro have this file.

Comment: Or it may be confusing on others. Ubuntu's will say something like "wheezy/sid" since they do not change this file when they sync Debian unstable.