# How to know which Linux and which version I am using

Tags: rhel, version

When I run `cat /proc/version` command in terminal, I got below output:

```
Linux version 2.6.18-348.1.1.0.1.el5 (mockbuild@ca-build56.us.oracle.com) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)) #1 SMP Tue Jan 22 16:39:05 PST 2013
```

If I run `lsb_release -a` command, I can see below information:

```
LSB Version:    :core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64                         :graphics-4.0-ia32:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-ia32:prin                         ting-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: EnterpriseEnterpriseServer
Description:    Enterprise Linux Enterprise Linux Server release 5.9 (Carthage)
Release:        5.9
Codename:       Carthage
```

As per the output of  `cat /proc/version`,  I can see that I am using RedHat 4.1.2. While as per the output of `lsb_release -a`, I am using `Linux Server release 5.9`. Which one Is correct?

If yes, how old is it? Because, I am not getting MySQL 5.6 installer for this version. MySQL 5.6 is available only by `Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 / Oracle Linux 5 (x86, 64-bit), RPM Package` version of RedHat.

- Where can I get MySQL 5.6 version for RedHat 4?
- If not, How can I know which Linux ( Fedora / Ubuntu / Red Hat etc. ) and which version I am using?

Comment: Seems like we have several questions in here.

Answer (score 27):

To see the distribution/version you are using, you can try:

```
lsb_release -a
```

Comment: I updated my question. Can you please suggest...

Comment: lsb_release: not found

Comment: lsb_release not found. Is there not something more default on any linux system to get at this question?

Comment: @chrismarx, not really. Bear in mind that the `lsb` part stands for [Linux Standard Base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base), which *is* an attempt to standardise this kind of thing across all Linux systems. Without it you will just have to try different things until something works.

Comment: to bad it's not there by default on centos, that was the system i was trying to find this information for-

Comment: @chrismarx, try `/etc/issue` as per [periket2000's](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/124836/48083) answer. It appears to work on Red Hat based distros.

Comment: Interestingly on centos6, that works, but on CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core), I get "\S
Kernel \r on an \m
" which is not very helpful. cat redhat-release works fine, once you realize you're on a redhat variant

Comment: As noted in several answers to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6345/5132 , as a general answer this is wrong, because the mechanism does not exist in several Linux-based operating systems nowadays.  _Specifically to the old version of Oracle Linux in the question_ it may be applicable.

Answer (score 24):

If you refer to the "comercial" or "human name" (not the kernel) you can do:

> cat /etc/issue

this give you

> Linux Fedora 13 (Leonidas)

Comment: The comments at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174881/5132 and at a deleted 2011 answer under that same question apply.

Answer (score 11):

The content `/proc/version` only gives you information about the kernel. It does not directly provide information about the distribution.

> Linux version 2.6.18-348.1.1.0.1.el5

This is the version of the kernel. `2.6.18` is the upstream version number. What follows is a distribution-specific built number. The `el5` suffix at the end is a clue that this is a kernel from [Red Hat Enterprise Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux) version 5.x or a derived version.

> (mockbuild@ca-build56.us.oracle.com)

This indicates where the kernel was compiled. Since it was compiled at Oracle, this is the [Oracle Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Linux) derivative of RHEL.

> (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)) #1 SMP Tue Jan 22 16:39:05 PST 2013

This is the version of the compiler used to compile the kernel. You do not have “Red Hat 4.1.2”, you have (or rather, the machine where the kernel was compiled has) version 4.1.2 of GCC, build number 54 from Red Hat.

The output from `lsb_release` gives you information about the distribution.

> Distributor ID: EnterpriseEnterpriseServer

This is a pretty unhelpful name; it really indicates Oracle Enterprise Linux (now called [Oracle Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Linux)).

> Release:        5.9

This is version 5.9 of this distribution.

---

The current major version of RHEL is 6, but version 5 is still supported by Red Hat (the plan is to support it until 2020). You're getting support from Oracle (if at all, depending on what you purchased), not from Red Hat; I don't know what their policy is. [Version 5.10](https://oss.oracle.com/pipermail/el-errata/2013-October/003711.html) is now out.

Since you've found MySQL 5.6 for RHEL 5, go ahead and install it.

Comment: My /proc/version had the operating system version as well: `Linux version 4.2.0-43 (root@ews-buildserver1204-01) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160603 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-3ubuntu1~12.04) ) #31337 SMP`

Comment: @dfrankow That's not the OS you're running, it applies to the compiler (`gcc`). And it isn't even the OS on which the kernel was compiled, but the OS which the *compiler* was built for.

Answer (score 5):

This looks like Oracle Linux, version 5. Check the file `/etc/redhat-release` This is an enterprise Linux distribution, largely compatible/comparable with Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 or CentOS 5.

The idea  of the enterprise Linux distro's is to have a long life cycle, 5-10 years, more compatible with enterprise requirements such as stability then bleeding edge, frequently updated distro's like Fedora or Ubuntu.

The consequence is that the bundled and supported software will be quite old. I'm unfamiliar with Oracle Linux, but they may have supported software channels with newer versions then those offered by default. I know Red Hat does. Those may or may not be included in your support contract.

In addition to there are the unsupported Extra Packages for Enteprise Linux ([EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL))  which should also work with Oracle Linux, according to [blogs.oracle.com](https://blogs.oracle.com/wim/entry/using%5fepel%5frepos%5fwith%5foracle).

The unsupported RPM packages offered by MySQL on [dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) should work as well if you don't want/need to get supported MySQL packages.

Answer (score 3):

Since in many Linux Distributions there are the info files placed in **/etc/** folder named ***-release** (**redhat-release**, etc), which contains distribution info and sometimes the version just select on the first of them and display it as follows:

```
$ cat $(ls /etc/*-release |sed 1\!d)
ALT Linux starter kit (Trientalis)
```

For your case I believe the correct distribution version is placed into the ***-release** file in **/etc**, since **/proc/version** just reflects linux kernel release and build host (I think).

Also there is a [**facter**](https://github.com/puppetlabs/facter) ruby gem, which gives you some facts about os OS, it analyzes OS release files, other data and prints to terminal screen. You can try is as follows

```
# apt-get install rubygems
```

Please use the case above that is eligible for your OS. Then install the gem itself.

```
# gem install facter
```

Then use:

```
$ facter
```

Answer (score 3):

```
cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)

cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.3 (Maipo)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="7.3"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.3 (Maipo)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.3:GA:server"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.3
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.3"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the [uname](http://ss64.com/bash/uname.html) command:

```
$ uname -a
Linux nodeName 4.2.0-0.bpo.1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.2.6-3~bpo8+2 (2015-12-14) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your ouput of `cat /proc/version`, you are using `Redhat 4`, the newest version is `Redhat 7`.

AFAIK, you can not run `MySQL 5.6` in `Redhat 4`, it's not supported by MySQL. You can refer to [this](http://www.mysql.com/support/supportedplatforms/database.html) for more details.

**Update**

It's my mistake. You are running `Oracle Linux 5.9`, according to `lsb_release` ouput.

`Oracle Linux 5.9` is fully compatible — both source and binary — with Red Hat 
Enterprise Linux. So you can go to [this site](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) to download `MySQL 5.6` and compile it to run on your server. (Or refer to [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html) to get it from mysql yum repository)

Comment: I updated my question. Please help...

Comment: Why these two command provide two different results? On which, should I believe?

Comment: `/proc/version` show the version of `gcc` compiler, you can run `gcc -v` to check.