# How do I know which version of Debian I'm running?

Tags: debian, version

In a tutorial, I'm prompted *"If you are running Squeeze, follow these instructions..."* and *"If you are running Wheezy, follow these other instructions..."*

When I run `uname`, I get the following information:

```
Linux dragon-debian 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.63-2+deb7u2 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Is that information enough to know if I'm using *Squeeze* or *Wheezy*, or do I get that from somewhere else?

Comment: Run `lsb_release -a`.

Comment: @FaheemMitha There it is: https://gist.github.com/IQAndreas/d7996a6b6f7bee12ec24 (though one of the answers beat you to it by a hair)

Comment: Possible dupe of http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6345/4671

Comment: @FaheemMitha Not a duplicate, that question asks what the version number is. This question is Debian-specific and asks what "version name" is being used.

Comment: That's basically the same thing. Version number and name (if available) go together.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Not in the case of Debian; none of the commands listed in the "duplicate question's" accepted answer tell me whether I'm running _Squeeze_ or _Wheezy_.

Comment: @IQAndreas I don't use Debian, but based on https://wiki.debian.org/DebianSqueeze and https://wiki.debian.org/DebianWheezy it sure seems like they're in sync. I reopened it since your question is maybe slightly different, but the only different part is "which Debian version is Squeeze and which is Wheezy", which seems pretty easy to resolve unless I'm misunderstanding something

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Commands to try:

• `cat /etc/*-release`

• `cat /proc/version`

• `lsb_release -a`
*- this shows "certain LSB (Linux Standard Base) and distribution-specific information"*.

For a shell script to get the details on different platforms, there's [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6345/how-can-i-get-distribution-name-and-version-number-in-a-simple-shell-script) related question.

Comment: It's funny you should ask, I just finished writing a related question which I share the outputs of those commands: [_What is the difference between all of these Debian version numbers?_](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/177207/5769) But sadly, none of the outputs say whether I'm using _Squeeze_ or _Wheezy_.

Comment: The last command you edited in (`lsb_release -a`) [tells me it's _Wheezy_](https://gist.github.com/IQAndreas/d7996a6b6f7bee12ec24); perfect!

Comment: @IQAndreas: Hmmm. It's weird that that you didn't also get that info from `cat /etc/*-release` on the `DISTRIB_CODENAME` line. OTOH, I'm not on Debian, I'm on a derived distro, Mepis 11.

Comment: @IQAndreas As tested on Debian Wheezy, all three provide the Debian version for me: (a) `cat /etc/*-release` shows Wheezy or, equivalently, version 7, on three separate lines; (b) `cat /proc/version` shows version number 7 in the suffix to the kernel build; and  (c) `lsb_release -a` shows Wheezy on two lines and version 7 on a third.

Comment: @John1024 _"... shows version number in the suffix of the kernel build."_ - Ah, so that is what `deb7u2` meant. From only glancing at it, I assumed it was the Git commit id.

Answer (score 29):

To get the exact version number use

```
cat /etc/debian_version
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question of the *named* version (e.g Wheezy or Jessie)

Comment: This answer should be the preferred general answer because it works on distros derived from debian. `lsb_release` gives the debian version only on debian itself. On Ubuntu 18.10, `cat /etc/debian_version` gives `buster/sid`, which is the named debian version I expected.

Comment: This one works in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

Answer (score 2):

`david@asus:/usr/share/applications$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.6 (jessie)
Release:    8.6
Codename:   jessie`

Comment: What new value does this answer bring compared to [the accepted answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177206/133107)?

Comment: This answer is from a new user, who needs to learn how to write better answers or edit other ones to add useful information.