# Debian version not matching kernel version and sources.list

Tags: linux, debian, turnkey

**Prelude:** Since i had a problem with apt-get, which was solved by commenting out the last line of it (attached at the end of this text), i started looking into what version of Debian am i running (MineOS Turnkey from around 2012-2014 more precisely) because apparently security support of Wheezy is about to be dropped.

**Problem:** Following the accepted answer of [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177205/how-do-i-know-which-version-of-debian-im-running) i got instructions on how to find my Debian(-based) OS version. Which seems to be Jessie 8.3.
Except sources.list (attached in the end) seems to belong to Wheezy, doesnt it?
Also the kernel is version is `3.2.0-4-amd64` ([which matches Wheezy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Debian_releases#Release_table))
Also what is this deb7u2 returned by some commands:
`#1 SMP Debian 3.2.65-1+deb7u2 x86_64"`?

**Results from commands:**

```sh
cat /etc/*-release
#returns this:
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"

cat /proc/version
#returns this:
Linux version 3.2.0-4-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Debian 4.6.3-14) ) #1 SMP Debian 3.2.65-1+deb7u2

lsb_release -a
#returns this:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.3 (jessie)
Release:        8.3
Codename:       jessie

uname -a
#returns this:
Linux pc_name 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.65-1+deb7u2 x86_64 GNU/Linux

cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list
#returns this:
deb http://ftp.ee.debian.org/debian stable main contrib

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib

#Third Parties Repos
#Debian Mozilla team
deb http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports squeeze-backports main
```

**My ultimate question is:** How can i update this system to a decent level or should i just download [a new Debian Jesse based .iso](https://minecraft.codeemo.com/mineoswiki/index.php?title=Main_Page#Pre-configured_ISOs)?

Comment: change all occurrences of `wheezy` in your `source.list` file to either `jessie` or `stable`.  You probably ought to do the same for the `squeeze` backport entry too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i decided to reinstall the whole system for stability sake.

1. I dont really know how many subsystems were broken besides the one i fixed
2. I dont know whether i actually fixed my problem
3. The .iso file definitely has all the interactions worked out