# if with regex in bash code

Tags: linux, bash, regular-expression

In `bash` I did the following. This `if` expression will evaluate to `true` if the Redhat version is 7.5 or 7.6.

```
if [[ ` cat /etc/redhat-release  | awk '{print $7}' ` == "7.5" ]] || [[ ` cat /etc/redhat-release  | awk '{print $7}' ` == "7.6" ]]
then
.
.
.
```

Can we do it in a more elegant way with regular expressions?

This is the content of `/etc/redhat-release`:

```
cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo)
```

Comment: Of course, using the `VERSION_ID` from the intended-to-be-machine-readable `/etc/os-release` is easier than parsing the human-readable string in `/etc/redhat-release`.  Luckily for doing that, this is RHEL (where bug #1240624 was fixed in version 7.2) and not CentOS or Debian or Arch.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/382537/5132 https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125241/5132

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this with `bash`'s built-in string matching. Note that this uses glob (wildcard) patterns, not regular expressions.

```
if [[ $(cat /etc/redhat-release  | awk '{print $7}') == 7.[56] ]]
```

Or, of we eliminate the [UUoC](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat):

```
if [[ $(awk '{print $7}' /etc/redhat-release) == 7.[56] ]]
```

or...

```
if [[ $(cat /etc/redhat-release) == *" release 7."[56]" "* ]]
```

or even (thanks to @kojiro)...

```
if [[ $(< /etc/redhat-release) == *" release 7."[56]" "* ]]
```

(Note that wildcards at the beginning and end are needed to make it match the entire line. The quoted space after the number is to make sure it doesn't accidentally match "7.50".)

Or if you really want to use regular expressions, use `=~` and switch to RE syntax:

```
if [[ $(< /etc/redhat-release) =~ " release 7."[56]" " ]]
```

(Note that the part in quotes will be matched literally, so `.` doesn't need to be escaped or bracketed (as long as you don't enable `bash31` compatibility). And RE matches aren't anchored by default, so you don't need anything at the ends like in the last one.)

Comment: very nice ,  this code is what I need

Comment: Consider `$(</etc/redhat-release)` instead of `$(cat /etc/redhat-release)`

Answer (score 15):

Far simpler just to check the release string directly

```
if grep -q 'release 7\.[56] ' /etc/redhat-release
then ...
```

The `grep` command matches by regular expression. The `[56]` atom matches `5` or `6`, allowing the pattern to match on `7.5` or `7.6`. Since `.` matches *any character* I've escaped it with a backslash so that it matches a literal dot. The trailing space ensures there are no other characters following the matched version string.

Comment: Personally, I'd use `grep -q 'release 7[.][56] '` -- IMO still fairly readable, and you don't have to worry about it failing when release 705 comes out. (or... does Red Hat use alpha-beta numbers like 7a5?) The big advantage of `[]` instead of escaping is that you don't have to worry about whether you might have to double-escape (or triple, or...) based on what kind of quotes it's in, etc.

Comment: That's an interesting approach. I had to read it twice though, so maybe I should have just gone for `\.` in the first place.

Comment: Linux. As easy as possible, as complex as needed.

Comment: Is the space at the end of the pattern intentional?

Comment: @Kusalananda yes it is. Anchors the pattern to avoid `7.59` or even `7.5.9`.

Comment: Apart from the better readability (in my opinion), another advantage of using `grep` here is that you could immediately "silence" any potential "No such file or directory" warning (e.g. if this script would be run on debian) directly with the `-s` flag.

Answer (score 3):

`awk` can do all the work of `cat` and `[[...]]` here:

```
if
  </etc/redhat-release awk -v ret=1 '
    $7 ~ /^7\.[56]$/ {ret=0}
    END {exit(ret)}'
then
  ...
```

Or just with standard `sh` syntax with simple wildcard pattern matching:

```
case $(cat /etc/redhat-release) in
  (*'release 7.'[56]' '*) ...;;
  (*) ...;;
esac
```

Comment: @pizdelect, that would always exit with `1`. If you wanted to exit on first match, you'd still need `awk -v ret=1 '$7 ~ /.../ {ret=0; exit}; END {exit(ret)}'`. Or `awk '$7 ~ /.../ {found=1; exit}; END {exit(!found)}'`

Comment: I've realized it immediately after posting it, sorry. I should install a userscript that give me some grace period before embarassing myself.

Answer (score 3):

Bash can pull out field 7 of a line using `read`, and these "/etc/*-release" type files tend to be one line anyway. Consider

```
read _ _ _ _ _ _ ver _ < /etc/redhat-release
if [[ $ver = 7.[56] ]]; then
    # match
fi
```