# How to determine that we are Bodhi Linux or other branches when the ouput for $NAME is "Ubuntu"

Tags: shell-script, shell, distribution-choice, distributions

On Bodhi linux, if I do this :

```
. /etc/os-release
echo $NAME
```

the output is : "Ubuntu", this makes it extra hard to determine what is what for a script.

and this will be important when calling apps you expect to be there.

I'd like to be able to determine in shell script when I am on Ubuntu subranches and what and also still be able to tell when I'm on stock ubuntu.

I implemented my own variant of this : https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/6348/228658

Is such a thing possible?