# Find package (OS distribution) manager for automation

Tags: linux, shell-script, yum, deb

I want to automate some installation process. For that, I need to know whether it is a DEB or RPM distribution, Im able to find some scripts for find the OS distribution.

I need to write a script to check the OS distribution and if it is CentOS, redhat, Amazon linux then print YUM. If ubuntu, Debian then print DEB.

Comment: Automation tools such as ansible do the abstraction of handling with the specific packet manager, there is no need to do it manually.

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6345/how-can-i-get-distribution-name-and-version-number-in-a-simple-shell-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sh
if command -v yum >/dev/null; then
    echo 'yum is available'
fi

if command -v apt >/dev/null; then
    echo 'apt is available'
fi
```

This would test the availability of the `yum` and `apt` commands rather than testing for a specific distribution (there are *many* Linux distributions).

If you have a preference for, e.g., `apt`, in case *both* package managers are available, you could do

```sh
if command -v apt >/dev/null; then
    echo 'apt is available'
elif command -v yum >/dev/null; then
    echo 'yum is available'
else
    echo 'neither apt nor yum is avaliable'
fi
```

Related:

- [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249)