# how do i check if my linux is deb or rpm

Tags: package-management, skype

The skype website offers downloads for linux in 2 versions DEB and RPM.
I don't know which one is right for my computer.

Comment: Perhaps https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6345/how-can-i-get-distribution-name-and-version-number-in-a-simple-shell-script or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/519773/find-package-os-distribution-manager-for-automation?

Comment: Who installed your system? Do you manage it?

Answer (score 6):

If `dpkg -l` produces a long list of packages, your system uses `.deb` packages.

If `rpm -qa` produces a long list of packages, your system uses RPMs.

If neither of these produce a long list of packages, your system another packaging format.

Note that in many cases you’ll need to know your actual distribution, not just what package format it uses. `cat /etc/os-release` will tell you in most current Linux systems.

Answer (score 1):

If your system uses RPM, you will have a program called `rpm` installed; if it uses Deb, you will have a program called `dpkg` installed. Whether a particular program is installed can be found out using the `which` command.

If you are new to Linux systems, I assume that you do not have a complex set-up, and since you are interested in getting Skype, I further assume that you are running a graphical desktop environment on your system. In that case, simply open a terminal window (the **Terminal** application if you are using GNOME, **Konsole** if you are using KDE, or something similar if you are using another desktop environment - usually, opening the main menu and typing/searching for `terminal` will show you the relevant application(s)), then type one or both of the following commands in the newly opened window:-

`which rpm`

***and/or***

`which dpkg`

---

*If the output shows nothing or `no dpkg in ...` or `no rpm in ...` it indicates the one that your system does ***not*** use. If the output shows just one path name and/or an alias name on one or more lines **without** the pattern `no xxx ...` (e.g., just `/usr/bin/rpm`), it indicates the one that your system uses.*

---

If both show single-line path name and/or alias name outputs (unlikely but possible), or if both commands show nothing or give a negative response, then your system may be using something different, and you will have to provide more information, such as the output of `cat /etc/os-release | grep -E '^NAME=|PRETTY_NAME='` as mentioned in [another answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/665951/218050).

There are other possibilities in general, but going by my assumptions, I don't want to confuse you more than is necessary!

Comment: There are systems with both `dpkg` and `rpm` installed, so simply checking for their existence isn’t sufficient.

Comment: @StephenKitt: That is why I added a link to your answer. However, I would like to point out (again) my assumptions, based on the simplicity of the question.

Comment: An answer to one of the questions linked to by Jeff Schaller in a comment above (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/519773/find-package-os-distribution-manager-for-automation) uses a similar technique.

Comment: Yes, and my comment applies to that answer too — some systems have both `apt` and `yum` installed. (Incidentally, you missed the last link in that answer, which is relevant to yours.)

Comment: No, I went through the last link, but I felt that adding all that information here would be too much of a digression, though for my own knowledge, I appreciate it very much.

Comment: which rpm: /usr/bin/rpm; which dpkg: /usr/bin/dpkg; Debian. The answer which said if dpkg -l or rpm -qa return long list of packages, that is what runs your system was a better answer because it's correct, non ambiguous, and easy to understand. It also covers cases where neither is running the system, for example pacman, in which case both are likely to return command not found errors. The original question was actually not right, since it's not rpm or deb, it's simply which package manager is running the os.

Comment: @Lizardx: It creates similar ambiguity in case both or none are installed. You need to know what to use, then.

Comment: @StephenKitt: I too referred to that question.

Comment: @Saurav “It creates similar ambiguity in case both or none are installed.” — I respectfully disagree. The ambiguity is the same in case none are installed; but if both are installed, only one will return a long list of packages, and that’s the one that’s actually in use.

Comment: @StephenKitt: I stand corrected, though, (again) going by the simplicity of the OP, I doubt if both are installed. My aim here was to answer the OP, not to create a general how-to, though the latter is certainly of much use but also more complicated. I have also added another answer, asking to consider installing a Snap package.

Comment: @StephenKitt: I suggested `which` because, seeing the simplicity of the OP, I doubted whether the added complexity of the other options would be worth it. The `which` command seems good enough for a beginner, and I would humbly request and advise against a debate on `which` vs the more recent/'correct' options here.

Comment: Anyway, I feel that the output of `cat /etc/os-release | grep -E '^NAME=|^PRETTY_NAME='` would make things much easier here.

Comment: OK, we’ll just have to disagree then; I don’t see how `command -v dpkg` is more complex than `which dpkg` ;-).

Answer (score 1):

There is another possibility - use a [Snap](https://go.skype.com/linux.snap) package. It works on most common distributions, and you don't have to worry about rpm, deb, or whatever, but you may have to install Snap support first. Instructions are [here](https://snapcraft.io/skype) (you may have to scroll down to select your distribution). If you use Ubuntu, `snap` is already installed, so you just need to install the Skype Snap package. If you have questions, you can ask here. Also, it would make it easier to answer if you provided the output of `cat /etc/os-release | grep -E '^NAME=|^PRETTY_NAME='`.